# When calculating the factorial of 100 (100!) with Java using integers I get 0

Tags: java, overflow, int, factorial

When doing this:

```
int x = 100;
int result = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < (x + 1); i++) {
    result = (result * i);
}
System.out.println(result);
```

This is clearly because the result is too big for an integer, but I am used to get big negative numbers for the overflow, and not 0.

Thanks in advance!

---

When I switch to this:

```
int x = 100;
int result = 1;

for (int i = 1; i < (x + 1); i++) {
    result = (result * i);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

I get [this](http://pastie.org/1675920).

Comment: This is not the best way to calculate a factorial.  You know that, right?

Comment: You're loop wouldn't calculate factorial even if you wouldn't get 0.

Comment: @duffymo: Yes, I'm just curious about the output. Thanks!

Comment: @Roflcoptr: I think it does, I just tested it for 9 with the correct result.

Comment: @duffymo Of course! After all, if I want `5!`, I'm not gonna do `5*4*3*2*1`. I'm gonna evaluate `gamma(6)`!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Big negative numbers are values that overflowed into certain ranges; `factorial(100)` has more than 32 binary zeros on the end, so converting it to an integer produces zero.

Answer (score 26):

There are 50 even numbers between 1 and 100 inclusive.  This means that the factorial is a multiple of 2 at least 50 times, in other words as a binary number the last 50 bits will be 0. (Actually it is more as even second even number is a multiple of 2*2 etc)

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    BigInteger fact = fact(100);
    System.out.println("fact(100) = " + fact);
    System.out.println("fact(100).longValue() = " + fact.longValue());
    System.out.println("fact(100).intValue() = " + fact.intValue());
    int powerOfTwoCount = 0;
    BigInteger two = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
    while (fact.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0 && fact.mod(two).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        powerOfTwoCount++;
        fact = fact.divide(two);
    }
    System.out.println("fact(100) powers of two = " + powerOfTwoCount);
}

private static BigInteger fact(long n) {
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (long i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    return result;
}
```

prints

```
fact(100) = 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
fact(100).longValue() = 0
fact(100).intValue() = 0
fact(100) powers of two = 97
```

This means a 97-bit integer would be 0 for the lowest bits of fact(100)

In fact, the number of powers of two is very close to n for fact(n).  For fact(10000) there are 9995 powers of two. This is because its is approximately the sum of n times powers of 1/2 giving a total close to `n`. i.e. every second number is even n/2 and every 4th has an additional power of 2 (+n/4) and every 8th has an additional power (+n/8) etc approaches `n` as a sum.

Comment: @Trufa: try this program with printing the (`BigInteger` and `int`) results after every step, to gain more insight.

Comment: @PaloEbermann: I did, I actually was able to solve this problem, but was curious about the 0 result. Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully I have explained why you get so many 0 bits at the end of the answer which is all you are left with when you do a large factorial. in fact fib(34).intValue() == 0

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I have understood most of your answer, I'm still going through the edit, math doesn't come too quick too me (but it comes...) :)

Comment: @RonK, Thanks for spotting that, changed it before I saw your comment. fib should be short for Fibonacci. fact is a better short name for factorial. Have written these fibonacci/factorial answers too many times. ;)

Answer (score 8):

To have a look at the cause, we could observe the prime factorization of the factorial.

```
fac( 1) = 1             = 2^0
fac( 2) = 2             = 2^1
fac( 3) = 2 * 3         = 2^1 * 3
fac( 4) = 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 = 2^3 * 3
fac( 5) =  ...          = 2^3 * 3 * 5
fac( 6) = ...           = 2^4 * 3^2 * 5
fac( 7) = ...           = 2^4 * ...
fac( 8) = ...           = 2^7 * ...
fac( 9) = ...           = 2^7 * ...
fac(10) = ...           = 2^8 * ...
fac(11) = ...           = 2^8 * ...
...
fac(29) = ...           = 2^25 * ...
fac(30) = ...           = 2^26 * ...
fac(31) = ...           = 2^26 * ...
fac(32) = ...           = 2^31 * ...
fac(33) = ...           = 2^31 * ...
fac(34) = ...           = 2^32 * ...  <===
fac(35) = ...           = 2^32 * ...
fac(36) = ...           = 2^34 * ...
...
fac(95) = ...           = 2^88 * ...
fac(96) = ...           = 2^93 * ...
fac(97) = ...           = 2^93 * ...
fac(98) = ...           = 2^94 * ...
fac(99) = ...           = 2^94 * ...
fac(100)= ...           = 2^96 * ...
```

The exponent for the `2` is the number of trailing zeros in the base-2 view, as all other factors are odd, and thus contribute a `1` in the last binary digit to the product.

A similar scheme works for other prime numbers, too, so we can easily calculate the factorization of `fac(100)`:

```
fac(100) = 2^96 * 3^48 * 5^24 * 7^16 * 11^9 * 13^7 * 17^5 * 19^5 * 23^4 *
           29^3 * 31^2 * 37^2 * 41^2 * 43^2 * 47^2 *
           53 * 59 * 61 * 67 * 71 * 73 * 79 * 83 * 89 * 97
```

So, if our computer stored the numbers in base 3, and had 48-trit-numbers, `fac(100)` would be 0 (as `fac(99)`, too, but `fac(98)` would not :-)

Answer (score 6):

Nice problem - answer is:
Factorial of 33 (due to negative values) is `-2147483648` which is `0x80000000`, or `0xFFFFFFFF80000000` if taking 64bits. Multiplying by 34 (the next member) will give a long value of `0xFFFFFFE600000000`, which when casting to int will give you `0x00000000`.

Obviously from that point onwards you will remain with 0.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution using recursion and BigIntegers:

```
    public static BigInteger factorial(int num){
    if (num<=1)
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    else
        return factorial(num-1).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(num));
    }
```

Output:

```
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

(Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11447287/4175601), adapted *slightly* to fit question)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BigInteger fact = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        fact = fact.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    System.out.println(fact);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BigInteger Class in Java. BigInteger class is used for mathematical operation which involves very big integer calculations that are outside the limit of all available primitive data types.

To calculate very large number, we can use **BigInteger**

> Like, If we want to calculate the factorial of 45, 
>   answer = 119622220865480194561963161495657715064383733760000000000

```
 static void extraLongFactorials(int n) {
       BigInteger fact = BigInteger.ONE;
        for(int i=2; i<=n; i++){
            fact = fact.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }
        System.out.println(fact);
    }
```

Main methods of BigInteger is BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.TEN, BigInteger.ValueOf()

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
public class BigInteger_Factorial {
    public static void main(String args []){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        BigInteger x,i,fac = new BigInteger("1");
        x = s.nextBigInteger();

        for(i=new BigInteger("1"); i.compareTo(x)<=0; i=i.add(BigInteger.ONE)){
            fac = fac.multiply((i));
        }
        System.out.println(fac);
    }
}
```

Output of 100 as input:

```
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

Output image:

[image: Output result]

Answer (score 0):

```
package test2;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial extends Big {

    public static void main(String args []){ 
    int x,fact=1,i ;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    
    System.out.println("press any dight and 0 to exit");
    while (sc.nextInt()!=0)
    {
    System.out.println("Enter the values ");
    x=sc.nextInt();
    if(x<26)

    {
    for( i=1;i<=x;i++)
    {   fact = fact*i;  }
    
    System.out.println("Factorial of "+x + "is "+ fact );
    
    fact=1;
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("In else big....");
    BigInteger k=fact(x);
    
    System.out.println("The factorial of "+x+"is "+k);
    System.out.println("RESULT LENGTH\n"+k.toString().length());
    }
    System.out.println("press any dight and 0 to exit");
    }
    System.out.println("thanks....");
    }
    
        
    
    
}
//----------------------------------------------------//

package test2;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Big {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        BigInteger fact = fact(100);
        System.out.println("fact(100) = " + fact);
        System.out.println("fact(100).longValue() = " + fact.longValue());
        System.out.println("fact(100).intValue() = " + fact.intValue());
        int powerOfTwoCount = 0;
        BigInteger two = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
        while (fact.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0 && fact.mod(two).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
            powerOfTwoCount++;
            fact = fact.divide(two);
        }
        System.out.println("fact(100) powers of two = " + powerOfTwoCount);
    }

    public static BigInteger fact(long n) {
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
        for (long i = 2; i <= n; i++)
            result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        return result;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: here I have extended this class from Big

Comment: and  maximum values 2450

Comment: its give limitless factorial program but the best results showing at 2450 and also depends on the hardware ,,System.out.println("RESULT LENGTH\n"+k.toString().length()); is showing results set length

Answer (score -1):

it's an overflow for sure, you can try double, 64 bit long integer are probably too small

Comment: Yes, there are -- a quick count shows more than 75 zeros, which is more than the 64 bits in a long.

Comment: Hi, thanks! this should be an comment, not an answer, and no, for 100 it would still be too small, the only way is using BigInteger

Comment: @Trufa: If you only need the result approximately, you could use `double` for this - it would be much faster than BigInteger.