# Big Hex to binary

Tags: java

I have looked at a lot of post here on stackoverflow concerning this problem, I have found partial solutions but so far I have yet to find a solution that works for me.
`new BigDecimal("3324679375210329505").toString(2);`
Seems to work best for me (from: [Convert a large 2^63 decimal to binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337828/convert-a-large-263-decimal-to-binary)) but I do need leading and trailing zeros. Is there anyway I can convert a large (bigger than a long) hex to a binary (String) representation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BigInteger class handles arbitrarily large numbers.

Trailing zeroes are allready handled. To handle leading zeroes, simply add a "1" at the front, which ensures a leading "1" bit, then strip it back off again:

```
String bits = new BigInteger("1" + hex, 16).toStting(2).substring(1);
```

Comment: @jlordo It does: `BigInteger(String str, int radix)`

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk: Yes, you are right, I was looking at BgDecimal. My mistake.

Comment: But I believe this solution get rids of leading zeros, and for proper conversion to base64(my end goal) I need leading and trailing zeros.

Comment: @Jordo See edited answer. (I realised the leading zeroes problem, but was busy for a few minutes)

Comment: @EliantenHolder as you can see, this answer does it in one simple line.

Comment: @Bohemian: upvoted. Didn't think of that nice trick. Can't delete my answer, as long as it's the accepted one.

Comment: Very nice code this was the kind of 'complex' code I was referring to in my comment on @jlordo code. I'm re-selecting the accepted answer but you still have my upvote  for the fastest and most simplistic answer! jlordo please don't delete your answer I think it demonstrates how you can do it 'by hand'.

Answer (score 2):

You need leading zeroes? I don't know of a built-in function, but you can easily implement it yourself:

```
public static String hex2binary(String hex) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(hex.length() * 4);
    for (char c : hex.toUpperCase().toCharArray()) {
        switch (c) {
        case '0': result.append("0000"); break;
        case '1': result.append("0001"); break;
        case '2': result.append("0010"); break;
        case '3': result.append("0011"); break;
        case '4': result.append("0100"); break;
        case '5': result.append("0101"); break;
        case '6': result.append("0110"); break;
        case '7': result.append("0111"); break;
        case '8': result.append("1000"); break;
        case '9': result.append("1001"); break;
        case 'A': result.append("1010"); break;
        case 'B': result.append("1011"); break;
        case 'C': result.append("1100"); break;
        case 'D': result.append("1101"); break;
        case 'E': result.append("1110"); break;
        case 'F': result.append("1111"); break;
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid hex: '" + hex + "'");
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Nice one. I suspect handling lower-case characters in switch might be faster, then calling `toUpperCase`...

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk: You mean extra cases? I was too lazy to type ;) No matter how long the input is, this won't be the bottleneck of the application...

Comment: Great that is the answer I was looking for, very simplistic yet very useful :)

Comment: @EliantenHolder: Then why didn't you write it yourself? ;)

Comment: @jlordo It's quite late and tbh I was thinking of a solution way to complex for the problem. I wish I came up with your answer by my self would have been faster :) Thanks for your fast answer you've helped me along :)