# Converting large decimal number into binary

Tags: binary, data-representation

I am tasked with finding the binary representation for the number 3.4219087*10^12. This is a very large number (and I have to do this by hand), so I was wondering if there was some sort of short cut or technique I could use to convert it instead.

Comment: You can use BigInteger to handle it.

Comment: "and I have to do this by hand"

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5372279/3711562)