# how to generate random number between 0 and 2^32-1 in java

Tags: java, random, unsigned

how to generate random number `between 0 and 2^32-1` in java?
I write link this:

```
long[]num = new long[size + 1];
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 1; i < size + 1; i++) {
num[i] = (long)random.nextInt()+(long)(1<<31);
System.out.println(num[i]);
}
```

but it print

```
-1161730240
-1387884711
-3808952878
-3048911995
-2135413666
```

i don't know why..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Very Large Numbers in Java Without using java.math.BigInteger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318068/very-large-numbers-in-java-without-using-java-math-biginteger)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is where you try to add an offset to avoid negative numbers.

```
(long)(1<<31)
```

interprets the 1 as an int, shifts it 31 bits which makes it the largest negative int, and then it it casted to a long (still negative).

You want

```
(1L << 31)
```

as your offset.

Answer (score 8):

If you want from 0 to 2^32-1, then you should use `Random.nextLong() & 0xffffffffL` instead of `Random.nextInt()`.

Java does not support `unsigned` types which means that your `int` cannot take values in the range you want. To get around this, you use a `long` which is 64bits and can take values in the needed range.

Comment: How does `random.nextLong() & 0xffffffffL` get you a random `long`?