# How Do I convert very big String to number in Java

Tags: java, string, numbers

Hi I have a big string like this :

> "999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999"

I wish to convert this string to long. But I failed. I did:

```
Long.parseLong(longString);
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "99999999.......
```

Are there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Note that using BigInteger as suggested below will remove the ability to use operators (+, -, *, etc). Just be wary of that... you'll have to use a = a.add(b).

Comment: [There are limits to the types of numbers that primitive values can represent.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318068/very-large-numbers-in-java-without-using-java-math-biginteger

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class like this:

```
 BigInteger number = new BigInteger(longString);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `BigInteger`. `Long` may not accommodate that big number.

Here is javadoc for [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Answer (score 3):

you might use [BigInteger](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/numbers/10biginteger.html) rather than Long.

```
 BigInteger number = new BigInteger(longString);
```

[Java BigInteger example](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-biginteger/java-biginteger.shtml)

Answer (score 3):

**long:** [Reference](http://java.about.com/od/understandingdatatypes/a/primitivetypes.htm)

use 8-byte to store values from `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`

As mention before answer, use `BigInteger`.