# How using large base is more efficient when writing custom BigInt in Java

Tags: java, bigint

[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318068/very-large-numbers-in-java-without-using-java-math-biginteger) is most likely the longest answer ever on SO. I am trying to understand the custom implementation but stuck at the very start Why author is using `10^9` as base instead of `10`? In this own words:

> As you think the decimal conversion is most complicated part, let's stay in a decimal based mode. For efficiency, we'll store not real decimal digits, but work in base `1 000 000 000 = 10^9 < 2^30`. This fits in a Java `int` (up to `2^31` or `2^32`), and the product of two such digits fits nicely in a Java `long`.

Secondly I could not understand this step:

> `int decLen = decimal.length(); int bigLen = (decLen-1) /`
>   `BASE_DECIMAL_DIGITS + 1;`
>
> This strange formula is a Java int way of writing `bigLen = ceil(decLen/BASE_DECIMAL_DIGITS)`. (I hope it is correct, we'll later test it.)

Comment: It appears to me that using 10^9 as a base makes it easier to handle large numbers while taking up less space, kind of like how binary(base 2) is often represented in hexadecimal(base 2^4). No idea about that second part though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5318896/763029

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using what we would consider a natural base, such as `10`, leads to lots of operations.  Have you ever multiplied two 9-digit numbers?  Using a method that we typically learn in school, that would involve 81 digit multiplications.  However, Java would use one multiply instruction.

What about large numbers, such as 18-digit numbers?  For us, that would involve 324 digit multiplications.  Here, the implementation would use 2 `int`s, equivalent to multiplying 2-digit numbers for us.  That would result in 4 multiplication instructions for Java.

Why not use a larger base in Java, to further reduce the number of operations?  Because of multiplication.  It is guaranteed that the result of multiplying two `int`s in Java will fit in a `long`, and 1 billion (10^9) is the largest power of 10 that fits in an `int`.  These operations are still very easy for Java - just multiply instructions.  It is possible to use a somewhat larger number, such as 2 billion, or `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (slightly over 2 billion), but that answer chose to use 1 billion, for human readability purposes.  Anything larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` would require something with larger ranges, but that's what the answer is already trying to do.

Also, using less `int`s in the representation saves on memory usage.

The code

```
int decLen = decimal.length();
int bigLen = (decLen-1) / BASE_DECIMAL_DIGITS + 1;
```

attempts to determine how many `int`s are needed in the internal representation to store the incoming number as a `String` representation.  It's 9 decimal digits per `int`.  I would have used `Math.ceil( (double) decLen / BASE_DECIMAL_POINTS)`.

Comment: for your `ceil()` call to work, you have to first coerce one of the arguments to a double.

Comment: Can you please explain the following part with an example ?  What about large numbers, such as 18-digit numbers? For us, that would involve 324 digit multiplications. Here, the implementation would use 2 ints, equivalent to multiplying 2-digit numbers for us. That would result in 4 multiplication instructions for Java.

Comment: @Walt Consider 222,222,222,222,222,222 times 222,222,222,222,222,222 (18 2s each).  For us, that would involve multiplying `2` by `2` 324 times (18^2) -- one for each `2` in the first number and for each `2` in the second number.  But for this implementation, it would multiply 222,222,222 4 times (2^2), one for each of the two `222222222`s in the first number and for each of the two `222222222`s in the second number.