# while calculating factorial the, i am geting garbage value even using long and double

Tags: java, long-integer

The program I have posted here is problem of [marbles from spoj](http://www.spoj.com/problems/MARBLES/), and I 
 know it has been discussed here, and I know the logic.

But when I am calculating the factorial, it overflows even on calculation of 29 factorial. What can I do?

long long is not supported

```
package marbles_spoj;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class combinations_with_repetition {

    public static long calc(long n,long k)
    {   
        System.out.println(n+"  "+k);
        long res=0;
        res=factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*factorial(n-k)); 
        return res;
    }

    static long factorial(long n)
    {   long result=1;
        if (n==1||n==0)return 1;
        else 
            for(long i=2;i<n;i++)result=result*i;
    //System.out.println("result is :"+result);
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter no. of marbles to b picked up");
        long n=sc.nextLong();
        System.out.println("enter no. of colors of marbles availables");
        long r=sc.nextLong();

        System.out.println("Number of combinations possible "+calc(n-1,r-1));
        sc.close();


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to calculate [factorials of large numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446973/find-factorial-of-large-numbers-in-java).

But you might use lots of `JVM` memory.

Example:

```
public class FactorialUtil
{
    public static BigInteger factorial(int n)
    {
        BigInteger ret = BigInteger.ONE;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) ret = ret.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Check out this **[`live demo`](http://ideone.com/Ghr8N3)**

Comment: Short and nice answer (**`+1`**)

Comment: yes i have checked your demo ,its  working fine (thanks),but can you tell me why 'double' data type returns  **1.21645100408832E17**
_(factorial of 20)_

Even though i have initialized variable as follows:
double result=1;

and not double=1.0;

Comment: well, First your answer refers to factorial of 19, please check your code for error/logical error or post it here. Second: 1.21645100408832E17 is in the e notation. Many computer programs/calculators present very large and very small results in scientific e notation. For example aEb is equivalent to  a*10^b. check : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation. 

Hope this solve your doubt. Please accept the answer, as it help everyone who visits this question in future.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that double should work and give you a good approximation of the value but you could use **BigInteger** from **java.math** for arbitrary precision math so you always get the precise number.