# Find a factorial of big numbers

Tags: java, biginteger, factorial

I have some method to find a factorial of big numbers. Could somebody explain, what's wrong with it and why i haven't any output?

```
public static long factorial(long num) {
    BigInteger numm = BigInteger.valueOf(num);
    BigInteger fact= BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    for (; numm.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)==1 ; fact = fact.multiply(numm)) {
        numm.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
    return fact.longValue();
}
```

Comment: You discard the result of your subtraction operation (notice how you wrote `fact = fact.multiply(numm)` to update `fact` after the multiplication operation?) That means `numm` will always be the same value, and the loop will continue "forever".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find factorial of large numbers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446973/find-factorial-of-large-numbers-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't assign the subtraction value to `numm`. This is the problem.
To stay with your code, use `num + 1` because last part of the for loop execute after the substraction made. So, need one extra iteration.

Check that:

```
long num=5;
BigInteger numm = BigInteger.valueOf(num + 1);
BigInteger fact= BigInteger.valueOf(1);
for (; numm.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE)==1 ; fact = fact.multiply(numm)) {
    numm = numm.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
}
System.out.println(fact.longValue());
```

Comment: thank you so much, my problem was about the `numm` assignation for sure

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's how you write a factorial. And why do you use `BigInteger` when you are returning a `long`? So just make the decision, `long` or `BigInteger`. I would choose `BigInteger` because you said you want to operate on very large numbers. You should use recursion to do factorial.

```
public BigInteger factorial (BigInteger number) {
    if (number.equals(BigInteger.ONE) || number.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    }
    return number.multiply(factorial(number.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
}
```

Comment: Factorial is a good example to show recursion basics, but in general if there's a so nice algorithm which doesn't require recursion, why should we use it?