# Handling 100! in Java / Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, biginteger

I know that `BigInteger` is the class to use when handling really large numbers. I wrote a simple script that calculates factorial. However, it breaks at input 25 and above.

```
/**
*    Calculates the factorial of a given number
*/
BigInteger fact(long n){
     def fact = 1
     while(n > 0){
         fact *= n--
     }
     return fact
}
```

**What is the right way to handle numbers as large as 100!** ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I get answer as `0` or some negative number

Comment: Overflow. It seems like `fact` is inferred to be a `long`, not a `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 4):

Just declare `fact` as a BigInteger with Groovy's `G` suffix:

```
BigInteger fact(long n){
     def fact = 1G
     while(n > 0){
         fact *= n--
     }
     return fact
}  

assert fact(30) == 265252859812191058636308480000000
assert fact(25) == 15511210043330985984000000
assert fact(100) == 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
import static java.math.BigInteger.ONE

static BigInteger fact(BigInteger num) {
    num.equals(ONE) ? ONE : num.multiply(fact(num.subtract(ONE)));
}
```

Also check the answer given by Peter here: [When calculating the factorial of 100 (100!) with Java using integers I get 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317732/when-calculating-the-factorial-of-100-100-with-java-using-integers-i-get-0)

Comment: Explanation, please :)

Comment: @LittleChild:- The link which I have posted has the explanation as to why you are getting a zero pr negative number. I think its because of the overflow as the most probable guess is that the fact is taking it as long rather than BigInteger.

Comment: @LittleChild:- You may try to change the method defintion as `BigInteger fact(BigInteger n){` or `BigInteger fact(long n){
def fact = 1G`and check the result.