# Java for loop, initialized variable meets termination requirements but loop doesnt terminate

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I've been researching this for a while but can't seem to figure out why this loop doesn't terminate.

```
public class Test{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        for (int i = 11; i > 10; i++){
            System.out.println(i);}
    }
}
```

The variable is initialized at a value that meets the requirements for the loop to terminate, so shouldn't there be no output whatsoever?

 Sorry if this is  a noob question but I can't seem to find the answer from searching (or maybe im just not wording the quesiton appropriately when i search)

 The loop just keeps executing until I press ctrl+c. 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Loops in java keeps going while the condition is true, not until the condition is true, so the loop will continue until it [overflows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo) to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1):

The second code fragment in a [`for` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) (here, `i > 10`) is a `boolean` expression that, if `true`, lets the loop run again.  It's obviously `true` all the time (until integer overflow).

Comment: oh okay. I was  under the impression that the loop was supposed to terminate when i was greater than 10, not the other way around. haha excuse my ignorance please. new to this. Thanks to those who helped.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop starts with `i = 11`, continues while `i > 10 == true` and at each iteration performs `i++`

Do you see how it doesn't terminate now?

Answer (score 1):

The loop will never end, the end condition states that the loop will stop when `i <= 10`, and given that `i = 11` at the beginning, the condition will evaluate to `11 > 10 == true`, entering into an infinite loop.

Well, strictly speaking it *will* end after the index overflows, but it'll take a long while to reach that point.

Comment: Yes, about four billion iterations later it will finally finish.