# Does Java Have Default Exception Handling for Arithmatic Overflow?

Tags: exception, recursion, integer, overflow

I have a program used to resolve tied die rolls using a RNG that is recursive and could potentially cause the variables in question to exceed the maximum allowance for a normal integer variable.

Will this cause an error?  Will it cause my program to crash?

Here is the code:

//This is the method in question.  Everytime it is invoked it multiplies the previous
//result of each roll by 100 and adds the result of a 20 sided die using an RNG

```
public void reRoll(){
    for(int i = 0; i < playerlist.size(); i++){
        playerlist.get(i).initroll = (playerlist.get(i).initroll*100) + Dice.d20();
    }
}
```

//This is the recursive call to that method.  If it receives too many ties, such as when it //is used several million times, it will cause the integer value to expand past its initial
//boundaries, potentially causing an error

```
public void resolveTies(){
    while(checkTies() == true){
        reset();
        reRoll();
        compareGroup();
    }
}
```

Keep in mind this code isn't fully tested yet, and this is my first time trying to talk shop with an outsider, (self taught) so I hope what I'm saying makes sense.

Comment: This sums it up nicely:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo

Comment: This isn't actually recursive, so you know.  A recursive function calls itself. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)