# Byte initialization using 0xFF instead of 0xFFFFFFFF

Tags: java, initialization, byte

I have a question about initializing byte in java, I want to initialize a byte value allBitsOne and all bits of it are 1:

**Method 1:**

```
byte allBitsOne = 0xFF;
```

Wrong, it says that 0xFF is a integer type and over the range of byte, so i do it like below

**Method 2:**

```
byte allBitsOne = (byte)0xFF;
```

Works fine.

**Method 3:**

```
byte allBitsOne = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

It works fine as well, but if `0xFF` exceeds the range of a byte, why doesn't `0xFFFFFFFF`?

Thank you all, I found this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

byte is a signed integer type, going from -128 to 127.

0xFF is 255, so it's larger than 127.

0xFFFFFFFF is -1, so it's within the bounds of the byte type.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: +1 There is no `byte` or `short` constants, only `int` (and `long`, `float`, `double`) constants.

Answer (score 1):

literal integers in Java are signed 32 bit numbers, so:

`0xff` is an integer type which equals to 255, which is over the limit for byte.

`0xffffffff` is an integer type which equals to -1, which is not over the limit for byte.

Answer (score 1):

the byte-variable in the java in the java can hold the values from -128 to 127.
if you want to set all the bit to 1. then u can store the -128 to it.