# Java incompatible types scenario

Tags: java, javasound

I'm learning Java and I've come across a scenario that has me confused.

Here is some code:

```
     long frameLength = stream.getFrameLength(); 
     int frameSize = stream.getFormat().getFrameSize(); 


    //total number of bytes = bytes per frame * total number of frames

    byte[] totalBytes = new byte[frameLength * frameSize];
```

The **int** type cannot take the value of **stream.getFrameLength()** as it's too big. That's why we use **long**.

But we can't use long because we need to pass in the value of (frameLength * frameSize) into a byte[] holder which has to be an int because java needs int sized arrays.

So, the above code will not work.

After some research I discovered this:

```
int frameLength = (int) stream.getFrameLength();
```

That seems to work, I'm confused about the extra "(int)" part added, what is this and what does it mean?

How is the above different to:

```
 int frameLength = stream.getFrameLength(); or
 long frameLength = stream.getFrameLength();
```

Here's the working code:

```
AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(f);
    int frameLength = (int) stream.getFrameLength(); //This is the number of bytes per frame in the audio stream
    int frameSize = (int) stream.getFormat().getFrameSize(); //Number of frames in the audio stream.

       //total number of bytes = bytes per frame * total number of frames

    byte[] totalBytes = new byte[frameLength * frameSize];
```

I'm confused, I'd appreciate some help!

Comment: It's called casting. It causes narrowing conversion. (Those are keywords.)

Comment: By doing (int) after assignment operator you parse the value into an integer type,- of course if that is possible.

Comment: As `frameSize` is meant to be `long` then i highly doubt you are doing the right thing by creating a byte array here with a large size like this. In fact narrowing conversion by casting long to int might easily result in faults in your application life-cycle. What are you going to do with this byte array ?

Comment: stream.read(totalBytes); to read the audio input stream

Comment: This is a terrible idea; what if someone tries to play a multi-gigabyte audio file.

Comment: As I said, I'm still learning! This is a project I'm working on as coursework for College.

Comment: @Elliott You can fit 3 hours of CD quality audio within `byte[Integer.MAX_VALUE]` :). Working with audio in this simple way is not a bad approach (mainly if you don't know anything about the specific use-case). It just lacks single `if` to check for too large files... and that is what should OP understand from any actual answer to this question.

Comment: @PavelHoral Assuming you have a little more then 4 gigs of ram to allocate. Try that on a 32-bit machine...

Answer (score 1):

> That seems to work, I'm confused about the extra "(int)" part added, what is this and what does it mean?

It casts whatever comes out of `stream.getFrameLength()` to an integer. Note that if it was a long that is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` you will get an [integer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo).

If you really need that int initialization of the byte array I would do the multiplication first:

```
long frameLength = stream.getFrameLength();
int frameSize = stream.getFormat().getFrameSize();
```

Then see if you won't get integer overflow:

```
long length = frameSize * frameLength // its a long because that won't overflow as fast as int.
if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    throw new IllegalStateException("Frame too large. Integer overflow!")
else 
   byte[] totalBytes = new byte[frameLength * frameSize];
```

This assumes the overflow won't happen (since we do not handle the error). If you do encounter this, you should find another solution in stead of a byte array.