# Reverse Integer leetcode -- how to handle overflow

Tags: java, algorithm, integer, reverse

The problem is:
Reverse digits of an integer.

Example1: x = 123, return 321

Example2: x = -123, return -321

Did you notice that the reversed integer might overflow? Assume the input is a 32-bit integer, then the reverse of 1000000003 overflows. How should you handle such cases?

Throw an exception? Good, but what if throwing an exception is not an option? You would then have to re-design the function (ie, add an extra parameter).

The solution from the website I search is:

```
public class Solution {

     public static int reverse(int x) {
            int ret = 0;
            boolean zero = false;
            while (!zero) {
                ret = ret * 10 + (x % 10);
                x /= 10;      
                if(x == 0){
                    zero = true;
                }
            }
            return ret;   
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int s = 1000000003;
        System.out.println(reverse(s));
    }

}
```

However when `s = 1000000003`, the console prints `-1294967295` instead of `3000000001`. So this solution still does not solve the overflow problem if we cannot use exception. Any help here?(Although there is a hint: add an extra parameter, I still cannot figure out what parameter I should add)

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo) link.

Comment: Throwing an exception *is* an option. You can avoid "redesigning the function" by catching the exception in your code. The value returned by the function will be based on whether the exception was thrown or not thrown.

Answer (score 24):

There's no need for any data type other than int.
Just make sure when there's an operation that increases a number, reversing the operation should give you the previous number. Otherwise, there's overflow.

```
public int reverse(int x) {
    int y = 0;

    while(x != 0) {
        int yy = y*10 + x%10;

        if ((yy - x%10)/10 != y) return 0;
        else y = yy;

        x = x/10;   
    }
    return y;
}
```

Comment: this didn't return 0 as expected for x=1534236469

Comment: this generates following runtime error
`runtime error: signed integer overflow: 964632435 * 10 cannot be represented in type 'int'`

Answer (score 11):

Above most of the answers having a trivial problem is that the int variable possibly might overflow. You can try this : x = -2147483648 as parameter.
There has an easy way to solve the problem. Convert x to long, and check if the result >= Integer.MAX_VALUE, otherwise return 0.
The solution passed all test cases on https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/

This is a java version.

```
public int reverse(int x) {
        long k = x;
        boolean isNegtive = false;        
        if(k < 0){
            k = 0 - k;
            isNegtive = true;
        }

        long result = 0;
        while(k != 0){
            result *= 10;
            result += k % 10;
            k /= 10;
        }

        if(result > Integer.MAX_VALUE) return 0;
        return isNegtive  ? 0 - ((int)result) : (int)result;
    }
```

C# version

```
    public int Reverse(int x)
    {
        long value = 0;
        bool negative = x < 0;
        long y = x;
        y = Math.Abs(y);

        while (y > 0)
        {
            value *= 10;
            value += y % 10;
            y /= 10;
        }

        if(value > int.MaxValue)
        {
            return int.MaxValue;
        }

        int ret = (int)value;

        if (negative)
        {
            return 0 - ret;
        }
        else
        {
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

Python version

```
def reverse(self, x):                
    isNegative = x < 0
    ret = 0
    x = abs(x)
    while x > 0:
        ret *= 10
        ret += x % 10
        x /= 10
    if ret > 1<<31:
        return 0

    if isNegative:
        return 0 - ret
    else:
        return ret
```

Comment: so far this is the best solution.

Comment: Well, it might work for Java, but it's not making sense - no integer should be more than Integer.MAX_VALUE - that's the whole point of MAX_VALUE. So, comparison ( result > Integer.MAX_VALUE) is always false.

Comment: result is a long, not an int.

Comment: This is smart, but I feel like you are treating. What if you were asked to reverse a long? Will you try to store the value into BigInteger in that case?

Comment: Current version of the problem states that you can't use `long`: `Assume we are dealing with an environment which could only hold integers within the 32-bit signed integer range.`

Comment: This is cheating. What about a environment where you have only INT as the max or like  very log memory chipsets.

Comment: Java solution does not work when you have input number 1534236469.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but anyway let me have a go at it too! I just solved it on leetcode. With this check, you never hit the overflow/ underflow in either direction, and I think the code is more concise than all the listed codes. It passes all test cases.

```
public int reverse(int x) {
    int y = 0;
    while(x != 0) {
        if(y > Integer.MAX_VALUE/10 || y < Integer.MIN_VALUE/10) return 0;
        y *= 10;
        y += x % 10;
        x /= 10;
    }
    return y;
}
```

Comment: It works. But why Integer.MAX_VALUE and Integer.MIN_VALUE must be divided by 10?

Comment: @Leomord well I think the reason I did that was that we will be adding x % 10 to the number so 0-9 is going to be added or substracted which could result in an over/under flow, so it is acting like a buffer to allow those values to be taken into account as well, you could alternatively add another if statement check after multiplication and pre addition and not use the div by 10.

Answer (score 4):

This java code handles the overflow condition:

```
public int reverse(int x) {

    long reverse = 0;
    while( x != 0 ) {
       reverse = reverse * 10 + x % 10;
       x = x/10;
    }

    if(reverse > Integer.MAX_VALUE || reverse < Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (int) reverse;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this code using strings in java

```
class Solution {
    public int reverse(int x) {
        int n = Math.abs(x);
        String num = Integer.toString(n);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(num);
        sb.reverse();
        String sb1;
    
        sb1 = sb.toString();
        
        int foo;
        try {
            foo = Integer.parseInt(sb1);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e){
            foo = 0;
        }
        if(x < 0){
            foo *= -1;
        }
        
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My soluton for this problem is to convert integer inputed to c-string, then everthing will be easy.

```
class Solution {
public:
  int reverse(int x) {
    char str[11];
    bool isNegative = false;
    int i;
    int ret = 0;

    if ( x < 0 ) {
        isNegative = true;
        x = -x;
    }

    i = 0;
    while ( x != 0 ) {
        str[i++] = x % 10 + '0';
        x = x / 10;
    }
    str[i] = '\0';

    if ( (isNegative && strlen(str) == 10 && strcmp(str, "2147483648") > 0) || (!isNegative && strlen(str) == 10 && strcmp(str, "2147483647") > 0) ) {
        cout << "Out of range!" << endl;
        throw new exception();
    }

    i = 0;
    int strLen = (int)strlen(str);
    while ( str[i] != '\0' ) {
        ret += ((str[i] - '0') * pow(10.0, strLen - 1 - i));
        i++;
    }

    return (isNegative ? -ret : ret);
}
```

};

Comment: I think the question was how to use the method signature and implement it maybe alter it by adding just an extra parameter

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
public class Solution {
    public int reverse(int x) {
        long tmp = Math.abs((long)x);
        long res = 0;

        while(tmp >= 10){
            res += tmp%10;
            res*=10;
            tmp=tmp/10;          
        }  

        res+=tmp;

        if(x<0){
            res = -res;
        }

        return (res>Integer.MAX_VALUE||res<Integer.MIN_VALUE)? 0: (int)res; 
    }
}
```

I tried to improve the performance a bit but all I could come up with was this:

```
public class Solution {
    public int reverse(int x) {

        long tmp = x;
        long res = 0;

        if(x>0){
            while(tmp >= 10){
                res += tmp%10;
                res*=10;
                tmp=tmp/10;          
            }  
        }
        else{
            while(tmp <= -10){
                res += tmp%10;
                res*=10;
                tmp=tmp/10;          
            }  
        }

        res+=tmp;

        return (res>Integer.MAX_VALUE||res<Integer.MIN_VALUE)? 0: (int)res; 
    }
}
```

Its C# equivalent runs 5% faster than the 1st version on my machine, but their server says it is slower, which can't be - I got rid of extra function call here, otherwise it is essentially the same. It places me between 60-30% depending on the language (C# or Java). Maybe their benchmarking code is not very good - if you submit several times - resulting times vary a lot.

Answer (score 1):

---

Solution In Swift 4.0 (in reference to problem from https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/description/)

```
func reverse(_ x : Int) -> Int {

    var stringConversion = String(x)
    var negativeCharacter = false
    var finalreversedString = String()
    let signedInt = 2147483647 //Max for Int 32
    let unSignedInt = -2147483647 // Min for Int 32

    if stringConversion.contains("-"){
        stringConversion.removeFirst()
        negativeCharacter = true
    }

    var reversedString = String(stringConversion.reversed())
    if reversedString.first == "0" {
        reversedString.removeFirst()
    }
    if negativeCharacter {
        finalreversedString = "-\(reversedString)"
    } else {
        finalreversedString = reversedString
    }

    return  (x == 0 || Int(finalreversedString)! > signedInt || Int(finalreversedString)! < unSignedInt) ?  0 :  Int(finalreversedString)!

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Last night, i have tried this same problem and i have found a simple solution in python, which is given below, here after checking the number type positive or negative, though i have tried in different section for both of them, i have convert the negative number into positive and before returning the reverse number, i had converted the number into negative.

For handling overflow, i have just simply checked with the upper limit of our 32-bit signed number and lower limit of the number, and it accepted my answer, thank you.

```
class Solution:
    def reverse(self, x: int):
        reverse = 0
        if x > 0:
            while x != 0:
                remainder = x % 10
                if reverse > (2147483647/10):
                    return 0
                reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder
                x = int(x / 10)
            return reverse

        elif x < 0:
            x = x * (-1)
            while x != 0:
                remainder = x % 10
                if reverse > ((2147483648)/10):
                    return 0
                reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder
                x = int(x / 10)
            reverse = reverse * (-1)
            return reverse

        else: 
            return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int reverse(int x) {
  boolean pos = x >= +0;
  int y = (pos) ? x : -x;
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
      String.valueOf(y));
  sb.reverse();
  int z = Integer.parseInt(sb.toString());
  return pos ? z : -z;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  for (int i = -10; i < 11; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%d r= '%d'\n", i, reverse(i));
  }
}
```

Outputs

```
-10 r= '-1'
-9 r= '-9'
-8 r= '-8'
-7 r= '-7'
-6 r= '-6'
-5 r= '-5'
-4 r= '-4'
-3 r= '-3'
-2 r= '-2'
-1 r= '-1'
0 r= '0'
1 r= '1'
2 r= '2'
3 r= '3'
4 r= '4'
5 r= '5'
6 r= '6'
7 r= '7'
8 r= '8'
9 r= '9'
10 r= '1'
```

Did you notice the reverse of 10 and -10? Or 20? You could just return a String, for example

```
public static String reverse(int x) {
  boolean pos = x >= +0;
  int y = (pos) ? x : -x;
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
      String.valueOf(y));
  sb.reverse();
  if (!pos) {
    sb.insert(0, '-');
  }
  return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  for (int i = -10; i < 11; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%d r= '%s'\n", i, reverse(i));
  }
}
```

Works as I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are required to return a 32 bit int, and still need to know if there was an overflow perhaps you could use a flag as an extra parameter. If you were using c or c++ you could use pointers to set the flag, or in Java you can use an array (since Java objects pass by value).

Java example:

```
public class Solution {

     public static int reverse(int x, Boolean[] overflowed) {
            int ret = 0;
            boolean zero = false;
            boolean inputIsNegative = x < 0;
            while (!zero) {
                ret = ret * 10 + (x % 10);
                x /= 10;
                if(x == 0){
                    zero = true;
                }
            }
            //Set the flag
            if ( (inputIsNegative && (ret > 0)) || ((!inputIsNegative) && (ret < 0)))
                overflowed[0] = new Boolean(true);
            else
                overflowed[0] = new Boolean(false);
            return ret;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int s = 1000000004;
        Boolean[]  flag = {null};
        System.out.println(s);
        int n = reverse(s,flag); //reverse() will set the flag.
        System.out.println(flag[0].booleanValue() ? "Error: Overflow": n );

    }
}
```

Notice if the reversed number is too large for a 32 bit integer the flag will be set.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use string to store the reverse and then print or use long or BigInt

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {
    /**
     * OVERFLOW
     * @param x
     * @return
     */
    public int reverse(int x) {
        int sign = x>0? 1: -1;
        x *= sign;
        int ret = 0;
        while(x>0) {
            ret *= 10;
            if(ret<0 || x>10&&ret*10/10!=ret) // overflow
                return 0;

            ret += x%10;
            x /= 10;
        }
        return ret*sign;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assert new Solution().reverse(-2147483412)==-2147483412;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {
    public int Reverse(int x) {

            var sign = x < 0 ? -1 : 1;

            var reverse = 0;

            if (x == int.MinValue)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            x = Math.Abs(x);

            while(x > 0)
            {
                var remainder = x % 10;

                if (reverse > ((int.MaxValue - remainder)/10))
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                reverse = (reverse*10) + remainder;

                x = x/10;
            }

            return sign * Convert.ToInt32(reverse);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we will use long to handle the the over flow:

```
public class Solution {
 public int reverse(int A) {
    // use long to monitor Overflow
    long result = 0;
    while (A != 0) {
        result = result * 10 + (A % 10);
        A = A / 10;
    }
    if (result > Integer.MAX_VALUE || result < Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (int) result;
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well This Suitable Code in Java Can be:-

```
public class Solution {
    public int reverse(int x) {

        int r;
        long s = 0;

        while(x != 0)
       {
            r = x % 10;

            s = (s * 10) + r;

            x = x/10;
        }
        if(s >= Integer.MAX_VALUE || s <= Integer.MIN_VALUE) return 0;
        else
            return (int)s;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution without using long:

```
public class ReverseInteger {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int input = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int output = reverse(input);
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    public static int reverse(int x) {
        int remainder = 0;
        int result = 0;

        if (x < 10 && x > -10) {
            return x;
        }

        while (x != 0) {
            remainder = x % 10;

            int absResult = Math.abs(result);
            int maxResultMultipliedBy10 = Integer.MAX_VALUE / 10;
            if (absResult > maxResultMultipliedBy10) {
                return 0;
            }

            int resultMultipliedBy10 = absResult * 10;

            int maxRemainder = Integer.MAX_VALUE - resultMultipliedBy10;
            if (remainder > maxRemainder) {
                return 0;
            }

            result = result * 10 + remainder;
            x = x / 10;
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the JavaScript solution.

```js
/**
 * @param {number} x
 * @return {number}
 */
var reverse = function(x) {
    var stop = false;
    var res = 0;
    while(!stop){
        res = res *10 + (x % 10);
        x = parseInt(x/10);
        if(x==0){
            stop = true;
        }
    }
    return (res <= 0x7fffffff && res >= -0x80000000) ? res : 0
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking care if the input is negative

```
public int reverse(int x) 
{

        long result = 0;
        int res;
        int num = Math.abs(x);

        while(num!=0)
        {
            int rem = num%10;
            result = result *10 + rem;
            num = num / 10;
        }

    if(result > Integer.MAX_VALUE || result < Integer.MIN_VALUE) 
    {
        return 0;
    } 
    else 
    {
        res = (int)result;
        return x < 0 ? -res : res;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution in Java will work:

```
class Solution {
    public int reverse(int x) {
        long rev = 0, remainder = 0;
        long number = x;

        while (number != 0) {
            remainder = number % 10;
            rev = rev * 10 + remainder;
            number = number / 10;
        }
        if (rev >= Integer.MAX_VALUE || rev <= Integer.MIN_VALUE || x >= Integer.MAX_VALUE || x <= Integer.MIN_VALUE)
            return 0;
        else
            return (int) rev;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler solution. Ensure that intermittent result does not exceed INT_MAX or get below INT_MIN

```
int reverse(int x) {

    int y = 0;

    while(x != 0) {

        if ( (long)y*10 + x%10 > INT_MAX || (long)y*10 + x%10 < INT_MIN) {

            std::cout << "overflow occurred" << '\n'
            return 0;
        }

        y = y*10 + x%10;
        x = x/10;   
    }

    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution coded in JS(Javascript, it has passed all the 1032 test cases successfully in Leetcode for the problem (**https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer**), also as asked in the question about the same.

```
/**
 * @param {number} x
 * @return {number}
 */
var reverse = function(x) {
    let oldNum = x, newNum = 0, digits = 0, negativeNum = false;
    if(oldNum < 0){
        negativeNum = true;
    }
    
    let absVal = Math.abs(x);
    while(absVal != 0){
        let r = Math.trunc(absVal % 10);        
        newNum = (newNum*10) + r; digits++;
        absVal = Math.floor(absVal/10);
    }
    if( !(newNum < Number.MAX_VALUE && newNum >= -2147483648 && newNum <= 2147483647)){
        return 0;    
    }
    return negativeNum ? -newNum :newNum;   
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution coded in JS(Javascript, it has passed all the 1032 test cases successfully in Leetcode for the problem (**https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer**), also as asked in the question about the same.

```
/**
 * @param {number} x
 * @return {number}
 */
var reverse = function(x) {
    let oldNum = x, newNum = 0, digits = 0, negativeNum = false;
    if(oldNum < 0){
        negativeNum = true;
    }
    
    let absVal = Math.abs(x);
    while(absVal != 0){
        let r = Math.trunc(absVal % 10);        
        newNum = (newNum*10) + r; digits++;
        absVal = Math.floor(absVal/10);
    }
    if( !(newNum < Number.MAX_VALUE && newNum >= -2147483648 && newNum <= 2147483647)){
        return 0;    
    }
    return negativeNum ? -newNum :newNum;   
};
```

The earlier answer was posted by the same user (unregistered). Consider this one.

Answer (score 0):

There are several good solutions posted. Here is my JS solution:

```
const reverse = function (x) {
  const strReversed = x.toString().split("").reverse().join("");
  rv =
    parseInt(strReversed) > Math.pow(2, 31)
      ? 0
      : Math.sign(x) * parseInt(strReversed);

  return rv;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I got all 1032 cases to work in python, I don't know how to remove multiple 0's such as 100, 1000, 10000 etc thus I used my if statement multiple times lol.

```
class Solution:
def reverse(self, x: int) -> int:
        string = ""
        y = str(x)
        ab = list(reversed(y))

        if len(ab) > 1 and ab[0] == "0":
            ab.remove("0")
            if len(ab) > 1 and ab[0] == "0":
                ab.remove("0")
                if len(ab) > 1 and ab[0] == "0":
                    ab.remove("0")
                    if len(ab) > 1 and ab[0] == "0":
                        ab.remove("0")
                        if len(ab) > 1 and ab[0] == "0":
                            ab.remove("0")

        if ab[-1] == "-":
            ab.remove("-")
            ab.insert(0, "-")

        for i in ab:
            string += i

        if int(string) > 2**31 - 1 or int(string) < -2**31:
            return 0
        
        return string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static int reverse(int x) {

        if (x == 0) return 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int y = 0;
        while (x != 0) {
            int value = (x % 10);
            x = x - value;
            y = sum;
            sum = (sum * 10) + value;
            if(sum / 10 != y) return 0;
            x = x / 10;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Extracting the first digit and dividing x to ten until x will be equal to 0. Therefore integer will be tokenized its digits.
Every extracted value will be adding the sum value after multiplying the sum by 10. Because adding a new digit means that adding a new 10th to the sum value. Also added if block to check any corruption of data because after 9th digit data will be corrupted.

1032 / 1032 test cases passed.

Status: Accepted

Runtime: 3 ms

Memory Usage: 38 MB

Answer (score 0):

```
Public int reverse(int A) {
        int N, sum = 0;
        int rem = 0;
        boolean flag = false;
        int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        if (A < 0) {
            flag = true;
            A = A * -1;} // 123 // 10 1
        while (A > 0) {
            rem = A % 10;
            if (flag == true) {
                if ((min + rem) / 10 > -sum) {
                    return 0;}}else{
                if ((max - rem) / 10 < sum) {
                    return 0;}}
            sum = (sum * 10) + rem;
            A = A / 10;}
        return (flag == true) ? —sum : sum;}}
#java #Algo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def reverse(self, x: int) -> int:
        if x<=-2**31 or x>=2**31-1:
            
            return 0
        else:
            result = 0
            number = x
            number = abs(number)
            while (number) > 0:
                newNumber = number % 10
                result = result * 10 + newNumber
                number = (number // 10)

            if x<0:
                result = "-"+str(result)
                if int(result)<=-2**31:
                    return 0
                return result
            else:
                if result>=2**31-1:
                    return 0
                return result
if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = Solution()
    print(obj.reverse(1534236469))
```

Answer (score -3):

Note that there are previous solutions that do not work for input: 1000000045
try this:

```
public int reverse(int A) {
    int reverse=0;
    int num=A;
    boolean flag=false;
    if(A<0)
    {
    num=(-1)*A;
    flag=true;
    }

    int prevnum=0;
    while(num>0)
    {
        int currDigit=num%10;
        reverse=reverse*10+currDigit;

    if((reverse-currDigit)/10!=prevnum)
            return 0;
        num=num/10;  
        prevnum=reverse;
    }

    if(flag==true)
   reverse= reverse*-1;
return reverse;
}
```