# How to resolve this error in reversing a number program

Tags: java

Given a signed 32-bit integer x, return x with its digits reversed. If reversing x causes the value to go outside the signed 32-bit integer range [-2^31, 2^31 - 1], then return 0.

I tried this code

```
class Solution {
    public int reverse(int x) {
        int rev = 0;
        while(x != 0) {
            int d = x % 10;
            rev = rev * 10 + d;
            x = x / 10;
        }
        if(rev <= 10000000)
            return(rev);
        else
            return(0);
    }
}
```

However, my code didn't give desired output in this case
Input:2147483647 output: -1126087180 expected: 0

Comment: Why would you expect 0? `rev = -1126087180` passes through the `true` branch of `if(rev <= 10000000)`.

Comment: While the loop looks ok at first glance (!), i don't understand the if/else after it.

Comment: If you extract the loop into its own function (e.g. `rev`), you can make the bounds check as `x==rev(rev(x))`. (if it reverses to itself, the number is fine, otherwise it went outside the range)

Comment: as asked on this site before, `7463847412` is not a valid `int` (too large)

Comment: If this problem has a web page, it would be polite to include a link to that page. For reference, the source of this problem appears to be https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/description/

Comment: This has been [asked several times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+reverse+digits+integer) on Stack Overflow. Do answers to this one [Reverse Integer leetcode -- how to handle overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070506/reverse-integer-leetcode-how-to-handle-overflow) or any of the others help?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways of doing this:

- everytime you calculate a new way for `rev` in your loop, check if an `int` overflow occured by checking if a positive value turned into a negative one (and vice versa)
- make `rev` a `long` and check if the resulting value is bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `less than Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: alternative: `Math` has methods like `addExact(int, int)` that check for overflow