# Why can I assign a number to an int which is too large and how does Java handle it?

Tags: java, arrays, int

Usually, when assigning a number to an     int     larger than 2,147,483,647, then the code won't compile. But in the following snippet,     result     is larger than (2^31)-1, and it can still print. I know that the "correct"     result     is obtained by letting     result     be     long    , but how come this still prints something and what happens behind the scenes? Thanks in advance.

```
public class intAssigning
{
   static int n = 500000;
   static int i;
   static int result;
   //static long result;
   static boolean [] array = new boolean [n];

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
      {
         array[i] = true;
      }

      for (i=2; i<n; i++)
      {
         if (array[i])
         {
            result+=i;
         }
      }
      System.out.println(result);
      //result with long: 124999750000
      //result with int: 445698416
   }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo

Comment: @Danstahr, thanks for the link, it makes good sense now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to assign a constant that is longer that the maximum size of the `int` you'll face a compiler error, and if you try to do this at runtime with a variable or some arithmetic manipulations that the compiler cannot detect the exceedance, it will over flow.

E.g. :

```
int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
i = i+1;
System.out.println(i);
```

output: -2147483648

Comment: @JonArnfred> You'e welcome, and hope to see you around on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The value cannot be *assigned*, meaning it can't appear at the right of the assignment operator, because it's a compile-time constant and is known to be out of the integer bounds, so it's not even a valid `int` literal, in a sense (btw, beside assignment, it cannot appear in expressions, argument to method calls, and anywhere an `int` is expected)

However, when arithmetics are performed on integers inside the JVM, values can *wrap* and you'll have negative numbers or otherwise unrelated figures, depending on the particular operation (addition, multiplication) and operands involved.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the value overflows. This means when you do this

```
int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
i = i+1
```

then the value overflows, which means it goes back to the minimum value (`Integer.MIN_VALUE`) and continues from there. If it underflows, it goes back to the maximum value and continues from there.

Your other problem is a feature of the compiler. It prevents you to assign a "bad" value at the first place.

Answer (score 0):

For your behind the scenes (with int 4bytes):[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's eaiser to understand arithmetical operation with overflow if we use binary representation, consider this

```
    long l = 0x7FFFFFFF;  // 2147483647
    l = l + l;
    System.out.printf("%x %d %n", l, l);

    int i = 0x7FFFFFFF;  // 2147483647
    i = i + i;
    System.out.printf("%x %d %n", i, i);
```

output

```
fffffffe 4294967294 
fffffffe -2
```

that is during int overflow bits above 32 are lost