# Positive division, negative result in Java

Tags: java, overflow, division

I'm really puzzled by this. I'm dividing two positive numbers and getting a negative result (I'm using Java).

```
long hour = 92233720368L / (3600 * 1000000 );
```

I got as result -132.

But if I divide them as two long numbers, I get the right result:

```
long hour1 = 92233720368L / (3600000000L );
```

Then I get as result: 25

I'm wondering why it occurs...

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Integer overflow strikes again!

Comment: Overflow. Your multiplication overflows. Also note that any operation on a `long` or `int` will yield an integral type - the mantissa will be truncated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo

Comment: How big is `3600 * 1000000`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must add `L` at the end of `3600` or `1000000`:

Example:

```
long hour = 92233720368L / (3600 * 1000000L );
```

Here's what's hapenning:

```
System.out.println(3600 * 1000000); // Gives -694967296 because it exceeds the max limit of an integer size. So 92233720368L / -694967296 = -132
```

That's exactly what's happening in your division, the dominator is an integer and is considered as negative number for the reason I stated above. So in order to consider the multiplication result of type `long` you should add `L` after `3600` or after `1000000`

Answer (score 2):

It interprets 3600 and 10000000 as type `int` which cannot hold enough information to represent their product, and so you get a different number. You'd have to declare them both as type `long` to get the correct result.