# get number of seconds since year 2000 using joda time

Tags: java, date, datetime

I am using JodaTime jar with Oracle Java 8. I am receiving packets from a firmware device and its beginning of time is beginning of day of January 1, 2000. I need to get the number of second since January 1, 2000. The math seems simple but for some reason it is giving me a negative value, which comes out to a time in the year 1999, rather than current time:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;


public class TimeIssue {

    private DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC);
    private DateTime zeroPointTime = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC);

    private void checkTime(){
        System.out.println("current time: " + currentTime);     
        System.out.println("current time to secs: " + timetos(currentTime));
    }

    private int timetos(DateTime time){
        return (int)(time.getMillis() - zeroPointTime.getMillis())/1000;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeIssue issue = new TimeIssue();
        issue.checkTime();
    }

}
```

output:

```
current time: 2014-07-09T21:28:46.435Z
current time in seconds: -1304974
current time from seconds: 1999-12-16T21:30:26.000Z
```

I would assume subtracting current time in milliseconds from year 2000 time in milliseconds and dividing by 1000 would give me the current time in seconds since 2000, but it is giving me a negative number. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Just a tangential comment: why are you using the joda time jar if your target platform is java 8?  Java 8 includes a time package (java.time) which has a very similar api to joda time without requiring the external dependency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have said, this is due to integer overflow. You *can* just add brackets:

```
return (int)((time.getMillis() - zeroPointTime.getMillis())/1000);
```

But it would be cleaner to use `Duration`:

```
Duration duration = new Duration(zeroPointTime, currentTime);
return (int) duration.getStandardSeconds();
```

Comment: +1 for the `Duration` anyways, but keeping it to `int` will make it work upto `19 Jan 2068` only

Comment: @Jigar: Yes, but I'm assuming that's a requirement. I suspect most code written now will be replaced by then anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

In

```
return (int)(time.getMillis() - zeroPointTime.getMillis())/1000;
```

the cast to `int` is applied to the subtraction **before** the division by 1000.

The conversion from `long` to `int` overflows in the `int` range, giving a negative value. Apply the cast after the division

```
return (int) ((time.getMillis() - zeroPointTime.getMillis()) / 1000);
```

**If** you really need `int` values.

Answer (score 2):

A note from [Joda-Time Home page](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> **Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to
> `java.time` (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this
> project.**

In Mar 2014, `java.time` API, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html), was released as part of the Java 8 standard library.

### Solution using `java.time`:

```
ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(zeroPointTime, currentTime)
```

where `zeroPointTime` and `currentTime` are instances of `OffsetDateTime` representing 2000-01-01T00:00Z and current date-time  at UTC respectively.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime currentTime = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        OffsetDateTime zeroPointTime = OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 1), LocalTime.of(0, 0), ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(zeroPointTime, currentTime));
    }
}
```

**Result from a sample run:**

```
727133121
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/ekm4iU)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of int overflow

remove casting and change return type from `int` to `long`

Current time in millis is ~`1404942594081`
Start time in millis is `946713600000`

difference is ~

```
458229057398
```

casting it to integer value would overflow to

```
-1332420848
```

because max value for `int` is `2147483647`

Just keep it in `long`

if you want to keep it to `int` this code will work upto `Jan 19 2068`

Answer (score 1):

Jan 1, 2000 was at roughly 946,684,800,000 milliseconds, which is about 458,257,821,000 millis ago. This number is larger than the number of milliseconds an int can hold (2,147,483,647). This means your cast to `int` will result in [integer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo), which is what you're seeing.