# How to resolve the id from MySQL DB into a variable

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Is is possible to get the `id` from a MySQL table and "save" it into a variable on `JDBC`?

In my program, I have a `JTextfield` in which the user gives a ticket which will be stored on a MySQL DB. Everytime he gives a ticket, I want to get the id from my db where the ticket was inserted and not print in on teminal, but resolve it into a variable and use it on other classes also. I need it for other classes.

Is is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
    statement.executeUpdate();
    ResultSet generatedKeys = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
    long generatedId= 0L;
    if (generatedKeys.next()) {
        generatedId = generatedKeys.getLong(1);// here is your generated Id , 
    }
```

Comment: So this will return the value of the id only for the ticket I inserted?

Comment: Yes. It is. Can you please check ?

Comment: Im checking it now.
BTW, why did you declare the id as long and not as int?

Comment: @vagg77 To overcome Integer overflow .

Comment: Could you please explain that?? I didn't get it

Comment: @vagg77 That means, In a large database Id's may exceed integer value :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59161/discussion-between-vagg77-and-ss-).

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
PreparedStatement st;
        st = con.prepareStatement("SQL STATAMENT", "HERE COLUMN NAME FROM TABLE") VALUES(?)",Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        st.setString(1,"Binded String Veriable");
        st.executeUpdate();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select last_insert_id() as id from "HERE TABLE NAME"");
        if(rs.next()){
          int lastId = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("id"));
```

Use PrpearedStatment to prevent SQL Injection for example:

`st = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO component(user) VALUES(?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS )
st.setString(1,username)`

Here you have how `last_insert_id()` works: [JDBC LAST INSER ID AND OTHER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-j-usagenotes-basic.html)

Comment: you can always change it to mine :D
Anyway hopefully it will help you :)