# Convert String to Long,No built in library

Tags: java, string, overflow, long-integer

I wrote Java code to convert `String` to `long`. However, when dealing with overflow problem, I don't have clues how to solve it. If a number is overflowed, computer believe every number is legal in storage. **How to let program, with 64bit jdk ,detect the real number is overflowed is the key problem**. And I'm not allowed to use any built-in library such as parseLong or others.

```
public static long strTolong(String s){
        //error checking
        if(s == null) return 0;
        s = s.trim();//remove all space character
        boolean neg = false;//judge the number is negative or positive
        int pos = 0 ; //index of string
        long result = 0;
        //check positive or negative
        if(s.charAt(pos) == '-'){
            neg = true;
            pos++;
        }else if(s.charAt(pos) == '+') pos++;

        //calculate result
        while(pos<s.length()){
            if(s.charAt(pos) >='0' && s.charAt(pos) <='9'){
                result = result*10+(s.charAt(pos) - '0');
            }else
                break;
            pos++;
        }
        if(neg) result =-result;

        //check overflow
        if(result >Long.MAX_VALUE) {
            return Long.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        if(result<Long.MIN_VALUE){
            return Long.MIN_VALUE;
        }


        return result;
    }
```

If **data is larger than `long.maxvalue`**, the result can't be stored in computer correctly.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: what is the issue in `Long.parseLong("102");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is probably to do a lexicographical comparison between the input and the minimum/maximum numbers before you start.

```
static int compare(String v1, String v2) {
    boolean neg1 = v1.startsWith("-");
    boolean neg2 = v2.startsWith("-");
    return neg1 ? (neg2 ? -comparePositives(v1.substring(1),v2.substring(1)):-1)
                : (neg2 ? 1 : comparePositives(v1, v2));
}

static int comparePositives(String v1, String v2) {
    // Is one longer?
    if (v1.length() != v2.length())
        return v1.length() < v2.length() ? -1 : 1;

    // Both empty?
    if (v1.isEmpty())
        return 0;

    // First digit differs?
    if (v1.charAt(0) != v2.charAt(0))
        return v1.charAt(0) < v2.charAt(0) ? -1 : 1;

    // Recurse on rest of number
    return comparePositives(v1.substring(1), v2.substring(1));
}
```

Use it for instance as follows:

```
if (compare(s, ""+Long.MIN_VALUE) == -1)
    throw new NumberFormatException("Input too small");

if (compare(s, ""+Long.MAX_VALUE) == 1)
    throw new NumberFormatException("Input too large");
```

Tested here: http://ideone.com/HmMkJ3

Note that the code does not check that the input is well formed. I suggest you do such check first. (Be aware of cases like `0` and `-0` etc.)

Comment: Your solution is impressive. However, the built-in library is used here. And the regular expression way is so as well.

Comment: The key problem is computer wouldn't notice the data is overflowed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo This solution does the same thing as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the same thing that Long#parseLong would do:

```
 throw new NumberFormatException("too long (pun intended): "+s);
```

Comment: The problem is computer won't notice the data is overflowed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you trying to achieve here. If `String` is greater than `Long.MAX_VALUE` means that is no more a `Long` value.

If your `String` value is withing the range of `Long`, you can use `Long.parseLong()` with out this kind of hard ways.

If you want to have huge number you can use `BigDecimal` easily

```
String max = Long.MAX_VALUE+"";
System.out.println(max);
long maxL=Long.parseLong(max)+1;
System.out.println(maxL);
BigDecimal bigDecimal=new BigDecimal(max).add(new BigDecimal("1"));
System.out.println(bigDecimal);
```

Out put:

```
9223372036854775807 // long max value
-9223372036854775808 // incorrect result in long
9223372036854775808 // BigDecimal gives you correct one
```

For your case you can throws an Exception if value is greater than `Long.MAX_VALUE` or lower than `Long.MIN_VALUE`

Comment: @aioobe what you are trying to say?

Comment: *"If String is greater than Long.MAX_VALUE means that is no more a Long value"* -- I'm sure the OP knows this. The problem he is facing is that he can't check for overflows by doing `result>Long.MAX_VALUE` since `result` is a long.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera The problem is computer would believe overflowed data is legal format. And I'm allowed to use Long.parseLong because that's built-in library.