# Java Prime calculator according to Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: java, algorithm, primes, sieve

I've stumbled on the following problem: I have a class to get and print all primes between 1 and N. The N is a parameter which you have to insert by yourself. When I insert 10000 for N, the code works and prints out all primes out from 2 to the closest prime to N.

When I insert 40000 the code still works. When I insert 50000 (or higher), the code gives an ArrayOutOfBoundsException. Why?

This is the code I use:

```
  ArrayList<Integer> priemGetallen = priemGetallen(n);
        for (Integer i : priemGetallen) {
              System.out.println(i);
        }
```

And uses

```
ArrayList<Integer> priemgetallen = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i = 2; i < n; i++){
    priemgetallen.add(i);
}

for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j * i <= n; j++) {
      if((j*i) < priemgetallen.size()){
          priemgetallen.remove(j*i);
        }
        }
   }
   return priemgetallen;
  }
```

The point "priemgetallen.remove(j*i)" is where I receive the error.

I'd really appreciate it if someone can tell me why this doesn't work for all N's bigger then approx. 40000.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: replace `j * i <= n;` loop condition with `j <= n/i`.

Answer (score 4):

The maximum value a Java `int` can hold is 2,147,483,647, so `j * i` is overflowing when `i` and `j` reach 46,341.

To extend the range, change the types of `i`, `j` and `n` to `long`.

See [How does Java handle integer underflows and overflows and how would you check for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo)

P.S. You'll also need to change `priemgetallen` into an array list of `Long` rather than `Integer`.

Comment: you would also have to change `priemgetallen.add(i);` to `priemgetallen.add((int)i);` since `List.add()` takes an int

Comment: @NPE Thank you! It all seems so logical when other people tell it, while it's quite hare to come up with by yourself. Have an invicible upvote.