# Why can I generate char beyond max value?

Tags: java, char

Why does  the following code **not** generate an error?

```
System.out.println((char) 2147483647);
```

According to [oracle datatypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), the maximum size for a `char` is `65,535`.

> - char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

Comment: And what does it print? Not `2147483647`. Why not? There's your answer...

Comment: It does a narrowing conversion, 2147483647 is an int, and you are narrowing it to be a char. As you have mentioned the maximum value for char is 65535. If you do a, System.out.println((int)(char)2147483647); , you'll see it prints 65535 not 2147483647. HTH

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Why can I generate char beyond max value?

`2147483647` is not a `char` but an `int`.

You're not assigning an invalid value to a `char`, you're casting a valid `int` to `char` and then *Narrowing Primitive Conversion* rules apply. See [Java specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3): **§5.1.3**.

In short you keep lowest 16 bits of original integer (*"A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T."*).

> Why does the following code not generate an error?

Because it's not an error, it's a well-defined behavior.

Comment: an `int`, not an `Integer`?

Comment: @immibis not an `Integer`, an `int`! ;) Yes, thank you. In origin it was _integer_.

Answer (score 6):

You do a narrowing conversion from `int` to `char`, which is allowed [see java spec: *5.1.3. Narrowing Primitive Conversion*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3):

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type `T` simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type `T`. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input value.

The resulting `char` isn't larger than [`Character.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_VALUE).
The compiler converts `(char) 2147483647` to `65535`

Answer (score 3):

`char` is a 16bit data type to which a numeric value can be casted to.

When you cast a 32bit integer to a 16bit short (or to char) you loose the upper bits of your source.

```
Int32 i = 2147483647; // 0x7FFFFFFF
Int16 s = (Int16) i;  //     0xFFFF (65535)
char  c = (char)  i;  //     0xFFFF (65535)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with any data type, it's called an `integer overflow` and when casting any bits beyond the size of the type you're casting to are cut off.

Comment: Half-half. Yes bytes are dropped. No, nothing to do with overflow.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the answer to your question is **you can't**.

Why you dont see any error?
Because `Character.MAX_VALUE + 1 = Character.MIN_VALUE`... Same as `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and others, `JVM` treats it as a loop to avoid this kind of problems... **but gives false results when try to calculate**....

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo) for further and technical info

Comment: Overflow? No...16 MSB bits are just discarded.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I'm quotting question linked..  but how I understand it can *try* to overflow... but does not happen...

Comment: There's no overflow when you cast. The most significant data is simply lost. This is the same behavior as older languages, like C++. Casting a primitive is the developer's way of saying, "Yes, I know I'm going to lose data, and I accept that consequence." Thus, developers should avoid casting unless they *need* to, because the compiler will protect you from doing stupid things by accident.