# Java - long displays wrong values

Tags: java, rest, long-integer

I have to create a program that goes from 1 to 100 and calculates the separate product of the numbers that have from the division with 4 the rest 0, 1, 2, 3, so basically i have to calculate 4 different products.

I tried solving this problem in two ways both ways display the wrong results:

First attempt:

```
    public class prodmod4 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int i, k=0;
    long P=1;
    while(k<4){
        for(i=1;i<=100;i++){
            if(i%4==k){
            P=P*i;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("Produsul numerelor care au restul %d este: %d\n", k, P);
        i=1;
        P=1;
        k++;
    }
}
}
```

When i run this program it gives me:

> The product of numbers with rest 0 is 0, rest 1 -6661643765781265135,
>   rest 2 -2885954222765899776, rest 3 -9150527387120197261

Second attempt:

```
public class prodmod4v2 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int i;
    long zero=1, unu=1, doi=1, trei=1;
    for(i=1;i<=100;i++){
        switch(i%4){
        case 0:
            zero=zero*i;
            break;
        case 1:
            unu=unu*i;
            break;
        case 2:
            doi=doi*i;
            break;
        case 3:
            trei=trei*i;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("produsul numerelor care au resturile 0,1,2,3 sunt:\n zero:%d\n unu:%d\n doi:%d\n trei:%d\n", zero, unu, doi, trei);
}
}
```

When i run this i have the same output as in the first attempt.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This could be due to simple overflow of the longs. Try printing your statement at the end of each loop iteration.

Comment: Check this SO question and its answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your numbers are too big for a mere [`long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), which supports numbers up to 2^63 - 1. When this happens, the result is said to [*overflow*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo) - which means that the results are not what you'd expect them to be. To solve this, you must use something that supports larger numbers, like [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) or [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) is what is wanted here, since the numbers involved are products of integers, and thus will always be integral.

Comment: I declared them as BitInteger and now it trows me the following error: "the method multiply(long) from the type BitInteger is not visible" at the lines where i have to multiply. Thanks is advance!

Comment: You can only multiply BigIntegers like this: `new BigInteger(4).multiply(new BigInteger(5));`

Comment: The way i did it was: zero=zero.multiply(i); and it gives me that error. So i can't multiply BitIntegers with integers?

Comment: zero = zero.multiply(new BigInteger(i))

Comment: Or bigint.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i))

Comment: @DavidConrad it worked with your solution! Thanks for all your help, everyone!