# Please explain this Java Program Output

Tags: java, casting, range, byte

Please explain why output of

```
byte c = (byte) (-512);
System.out.print(c);
```

is `0`.

Comment: What is confusing you about it? Do you know what is [range of `byte`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Java handle integer underflows and overflows and how would you check for it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo)

Comment: Yes I do..its -128 to 127 but why is the output 0

Comment: Try to print results for `-129`,`-130` ...  `-512` and observe what happens.

Comment: Got it..If it goes out of range the final value will be value%256(modulo)  correct?

Answer (score 1):

The range of byte in Java is `-128 to 127`. Since -512 is not in the range, the compiler will ask for explicit typecasting. Hence, you have to cast the -512 (an integer) to byte. What happens when the program runs is that, JVM just removes the upper 24 bits to fit -512 in 8 bits.

```
-512         = 11111111111111110000001000000000 (int)
(byte) -512  =                         00000000 (byte) //truncated the upper 24 bits// = 0
```