# Core java for loop with if condition explanation

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

Hi Guys when am running below program

```
package com.test;

public class Test1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i=5;
     for(;;i++){

        if(i<0){
            System.out.println("Break");
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Output :  Break.

How it is possible ? Can any one explain

thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hint: what's the biggest `int` value? If `i` has that value, what is the new value of it after `i++` executes?

Comment: It is called an integer overflow. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this line to your code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i=5;
     for(;;i++){
        System.out.println("Current i: " + i);
        if(i<0){
            System.out.println("Break");
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

You will see that after [Integer.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) it will start over at [Integer.MIN_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE) and reach eventually zero at some time.

Comment: "You will see that after Integer.MAX_VALUE it will start over at 0." That is incorrect. It jumps to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: @Turing85 Thx. you are right.

Answer (score 0):

i initialize with five and loop will iterate till int maximum value of 
+2147483647 after that value comes again start from lowest value of int that is -2147483648 so when negative value starts if condition satisfied and print break.

Answer (score 0):

this is the case of number system definition in number system definition.(Digital electronics and Number Systems).

Any progarmming language thers is number system for example for 8 bit signed integer it is -128 to 127.

so if you will put 128 it will be counted as -128.
if you put 130 it will be counted as -126.

sowhen max positive integer values exceeds number becomes negative and condtion becomes true.
thats why breakis out put .

insert sop(i) in the loop , you will understand.