# How can I change the values exceeding the int data type to the long data type in this code?

Tags: java, int, long-integer

In the last portion of this code (where the last for loop and if statements are), I'm trying to change the data type of the `integers` to `long` when they exceed the integer data type limit. What am I doing wrong in this code? When I run, I get the same values as before I even tried to change them to long (which are increasingly huge integers until they get negative).

```
public class UniqueElements {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxValue = 0;
        int numElements = 0;
        int programRuns = 12;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int newExecution = 0; newExecution <= programRuns; newExecution++ ) {
            System.out.print("Enter the maximum value for an element: ");
            //prompt user to enter the maximum value
            maxValue = sc.nextInt(); //user input for max value
            System.out.print("Enter the number of elements in the array: ");
            numElements = sc.nextInt(); //number of elements in an array
            int A[] = new int[numElements];
            //array comprising of the number of elements chosen by the user
            int totalComp = 0; //set total comparisons to 0
            for (int runs = 1; runs <= 100; runs++) { //program runs 100 times
                Random rand = new Random(System.nanoTime());
                //initiate the random number generator
                int numComp = 0; //set number of comparisons to 0
                for (int index = 0; index < numElements; index++) { 
                    A[index] = rand.nextInt(maxValue); 
                    //length of array is the number of elements the user puts in
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) { //for each integer in the array
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < A.length; j++) { 
                        //for each integer following i
                        if (A[i] == A[j]) { //if the are equal to eachother
                            //end the if statement
                            break;
                        }
                        if (numComp == (int)numComp) {
                           numComp++; 
                        }
                        else {
                            Long.valueOf(numComp);
                            numComp++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                totalComp+= numComp; 
            } //end 100 loops
            if (totalComp == (int)totalComp) 
                System.out.println("Average number of comparisons: " + totalComp / 100);
            else {
                System.out.println("Average number of comparisons: " + 
                                    Long.valueOf(totalComp) / 100L);
            }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

update:

somehow.... changing the total number of runs to 2 and dividing the totalComp variable by 2 and 2L made it work. Anyone know how that changed it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the type of a variable after it's already been declared. You can cast that variable to another type, or "interpret" it as another type (as in your `Long.valueOf()`), but the variable still remains whatever type you declared it as.

In your code, you've declared `totalComp` to be an `int`, which in Java means it holds 32 bits (one of which is a sign bit). There's no way to make Java store more than 32 bits in an int. If you continue to add beyond `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, or subtract below `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, the value in the variable will simply under/overflow. So this statement after your for loop  isn't doing what you expect, and will always be true: `if (totalComp == (int)totalComp)`

In other words, you can't go "back in time" and re-declare your primitive `int` as a `long` because you found out at runtime that you need to store larger values. The easiest way to solve this problem would be to declare `totalComp` as a `long`. If for some reason you can't change the type of `totalComp`, it is possible to detect overflow/underflow before performing the calculation; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3001879/4256475) for details.