# Leetcode Coin Change DP JAVA java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I am working on this problem on Leetcode 322 Coin Change.

The question is; You are given coins of different denominations and a total amount of money amount, write a function to compute the fewest number of coins that you need to make up that amount. If that amount of money cannot be made up by any combination of the coins, return -1.

> **Example 1**
>
> coins = [1, 2, 5], amount = 11
>
> return 3 (11 = 5 + 5 + 1)
>
> **Example 2**
>
> coins = [2], amount = 3
>
> return -1

The following is JAVA DP Solution;

```
public int coinChange(int[] coins, int amount) {
    
if(amount==0) return 0;

int[] dp = new int[amount+1];
dp[0]=0; // do not need any coin to get 0 amount
for(int i=1;i<=amount; i++)
    dp[i]= Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for(int i=0; i<=amount; i++){
    for(int coin: coins){
        if(i+coin <=amount){
            if(dp[i]!=Integer.MAX_VALUE){
                if(dp[i+coin] >= dp[i] + 1)
                    dp[i+coin] = dp[i] + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

if(dp[amount] >= Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    return -1;

return dp[amount];
}
```

When I run the test case with `coins = [1,2147483646], amount = 2`
I always get the error message

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2147483648  for line
>
> if(dp[i+coin] >= dp[i] + 1)

I am trying to understand why it would happen. I am thinking the coin value `2147483646` won't pass this line `if(i+coin <=amount)` to affect the following code. right?

SOLVED! By change if(i+coin <=amount) to if(i+coin <=amount && i + coin >=0))

Comment: [How does Java handle integer underflows and overflows and how would you check for it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3001836/669576).

Comment: Why are you using the array of  that big size `long[] dp = new long [amount+1];` You are passing amount to initialize the array which is `2147483647` is it really needed? Overflow occurs in your code.