# Oracle Certified Associate Assessment Snippet

Tags: java

I've taken this excerpt from the OCA Programmer Assessment test. I have changed the code slightly a little.

```
public class FeedingSchedule {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x=5, j=0;
        OUTER: for(int i=0; i<3; )
            INNER: do {
                i++; x++;
                if(x>10) continue INNER;
                x+=4;
                j++;
            } while(j<=2);

        System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
```

can someone tell me why this returns -2147483639? my initial assumption was that the code should run forever and not quit.

Any replies as to the explanation of the code will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"Here's some code, please explain it for me"_ are considered off-topic.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Comment: You *could* just throw this into an IDE with a debugger and *execute* it, since it's an easily-run snippet...

Comment: Also, that's crap code.  If I had a programmer working for me who wrote that code I'd have a serious talk with him/her.  This is unmaintainable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3001836/669576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the value of x. Its starts with 5, then it is incremented by 1, then by 4. At a certain point it is greater than 10, then the continue with label comes into play: x is incremented until an overflow occurs. 
The overflow stops the loop "Inner: ... continue Inner", so the rest of the outer loop is executed.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks very much.