# Possible issue with `PriorityQueue<Integer>` when used on values approaching `Integer.Max_Value`

Tags: java, sorting, intellij-idea

I am using a priority queue act as a min heap such that I can merge lists. These lists are on separate disks and hence this style of merging should be most efficient.

When I run the following code on small datasets (-1000 -> 1000 range) they are sorted perfectly. However when I run it on a larger range the priority queue isn't correctly sorted.

This is the code that I am using to create and initially populate the Priority Queue.

```
RandomAccessFile sourceRandom = new RandomAccessFile(file1, "r");
RandomAccessFile destRandom = new RandomAccessFile(file2, "rw");
PriorityQueue<HeapNode> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(1, (o1, o2) -> o1.Value - o2.Value);

//create and populate an array of indexes for the start of each unmerged partition
long[] startIdxArray = new long[k];
for(int ki = 0; ki < k ; ki++){
    startIdxArray[ki] = sortableSize * (long)ki;
}

long[] idxArray = startIdxArray.clone();

//populate the heap with the first value from the partition
for(int ki = 0; ki < k; ki++){
    sourceRandom.seek(idxArray[ki]);
    minHeap.add(new HeapNode(sourceRandom.readInt(), ki));
    idxArray[ki] += 4;
}
```

HeapNode Class:

```
class HeapNode{
    public int kIdx;
    public int Value;

    public HeapNode(int value, int KIdx){
        kIdx = KIdx;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

This is the output of the minHeap:

[image: structure of minHeap - not Working]

This is formatted by Intellij in the debugging pane.
Additionally this is what is actually output by the `minHeap.poll()` method.

I would just like to additionally note that this code works 100% when the values that are read into the priority queue are ~[-1000 -> 1000]:

`[4, 3, 2, 1, 128, 256, 1024, 65536, -128, -256, 512, -227, -1]` works correctly when split into 7 lists of two elements.

[image: structure of minHeap - Working]

These were also stopped at the same point of execution: just after the pasted code.

I am using a minimum heap for `O(log(n))` extraction of the minimum term resulting on `O(n log(n))` sorting time rather than `O(n^2)`

Thanks for any help you can give me with this or even steps to take to try and debug this.

Notes:

This is a windows 10 PC running Win10Home,

JDK: `1.8.0_112` (this is what the folder is called in `ProgramFiles` at least

Comment: Your `-` operation is overflowing. Use `Integer.compare(o1.Value, o2.Value)`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I thought that java threw an runtime exception for operations that overflow? Or at least performed the operation at double precision for operations that could overflow (see multiplication)

Comment: No https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I seem to remember getting one at some point but it was probably in another language