# Obtaining Fibonacci Series with BigInteger without using Recursion

Tags: java, arrays, fibonacci

Hello all beginner programmer here, having a hard time calculating a fibonacci series without recursion.

My main issue is using `BigInteger` with it. Here is my code :

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class Fibonacci
{
   public void fibonacci(int n)
   {
      int[] arr = new int[n + 1];

      arr[0] = 0;
      arr[1] = 1;
      arr[2] = 1;

      for(int i = 3; i <= n; i++)
      {
         arr[i] = arr[i-1] + arr[i-2];             
      }

      System.out.println(arr[n]);           
   }     
}
```

Here is my man method tester

```
public class TestFibonacci
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Fibonacci f1 = new Fibonacci();

      f1.fibonacci(3);
      f1.fibonacci(10);
      f1.fibonacci(20);
      f1.fibonacci(30);
      f1.fibonacci(40);
      f1.fibonacci(50);
      f1.fibonacci(60);
      f1.fibonacci(100);
   }
}
```

My current output works up to 40 after I start getting the negative numbers, any tips??

```
2
55
6765
832040
102334155
-298632863
1820529360
-980107325
```

Comment: You're not using BigInteger here, so ?

Comment: Where are you using `BigInteger`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you'd better use `BigInteger`, because without you'll get [`integer overflow`(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo)  **:**

```
public void fibonacci(int n) {
    BigInteger[] arr = new BigInteger[n + 1];

    arr[0] = BigInteger.ZERO;
    arr[1] = BigInteger.ONE;
    arr[2] = BigInteger.ONE;

    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1].add(arr[i - 2]);
    }

    System.out.println(arr[n]);
}
```

---

And you'll get :

```
2
55
6765
832040
102334155
12586269025
1548008755920
354224848179261915075
```

Comment: Thanks Azro, still learning more and more about java and you have clarified exactly what I was asking. Also was it necessary for me to have to declare the first three big ints in the array? I figured I would have too.

Answer (score -1):

Just declare your array to store BigIntegers:

```
BigInteger[] arr = new BigInteger[n + 1];
```

Initialize your first values with the `BigInteger.ONE` and `BigInteger.ZERO`:

```
arr[0] = BigInteger.ZERO;
arr[1] = BigInteger.ONE;
```

At the end just use the add method:

```
arr[i] = arr[i - 1].add(arr[i - 1]);
```