# Implicit type casting in char

Tags: java, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I am a beginner to java. Today, I was watching the tutorial and I got to know that we can assign integer value to char datatype like:

```
char a = 65;
```

and when we print

```
System.out.print(a);
```

Then, it will give us character value.

> A

Why is it?

I have read that implicit type conversion is also known as widening. But char type is smaller in size than int. Then, why the conversion?

Comment: As an aside: `char a = 65;` is not an implicit converstion since `65` is a `char` literal.

Answer (score 0):

`char a = 65;` gives **A**, because each character is associated with number, this is [the ASCII code.](https://theasciicode.com.ar/) (66 for B, ...etc)

a char in java takes 2 Bytes (16 bits)

When you try to assign an integer that is less than or equal 0xFFFF to a char variable, its work. But when you try to assign a number greater than that (example `char a = 0xFFFF+1;`) it gives you an error. The 0xFFFF is the maximum value that 2 bytes can hold.

good luck.

Comment: But, why the implicit type conversion from int to char. According to the definition, it should go from smaller datatype to larger datatype

Comment: @TabassumAzmi you can refer to the already existing question about converting int (4 bytes) to char with smaller size (2 bytes) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829613/internal-conversion-of-integer-to-char-whose-size-is-smaller