# Estimate int value of a number

Tags: int

> What is the **int** value of 456789*456789? (regular 32-bit representation)
>
> edit - sharping the question: what is the 4 bytes representation of the value?

1) **-1,797,206,983**

2) 206,656,190,521

3) 2,497,760,313

4) 350,276,665

5) No value: the code terminated with error message.

---

I know the answer is 1. 
I wonder how one can answer this question without calculator or any other utilities (like in a test)

Comment: That depends on the language, `int` has different meanings depending on the language .

Comment: The exact behavior depends, if you try that expression in C# it would actually not compile because it overflow int, and since you haven't explicitly stated that you want long (64-bit) it won't even compile the expression for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach when reading your question:

- the answer is going to be larger than 400000 * 400000, which is 16 and ten zeroes (this calculation I can do in my head), so answers 3 and 4 can be excluded.
- I know (simply because I just know a couple of common powers of two) that a 32bit value can hold something like 4.2 billion values, so answer 2 can be excluded too because the value is too large to fit into 32bit

So I'd go for answer 1) (without knowing whether it's correct).

Comment: That would be my approach too , though I wonder if there's another way 
to like.. know its gonna be negative or something like that

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the specific language manages overflow in data type operations, *e.g.*

- **Java** ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo)), **C** and **C++** go back to the minimum value and continue from there, returning `-1797206983`;
- **C#** returns the compile error "The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode";
- **PHP** and **JavaScript** (example below) return `208656190521`.

```js
console.log(456789 * 456789);
```

Comment: I guess this would be the most accurate answer, but if we assume it's java 
or like what happens when I use windows 10 calculator on programmer mode
how would you answer this question on paper? you have 4 bytes to represent the result how would you know its option 1?