# Reverse Integer Leetcode - Explain overflow issue

Tags: java, overflow

I am new to coding and practicing leetcode problems. Integer reverse problem talks about overflow.

I have searched and most of the discussion about how to handle the overflow. Could someone explain what is this overflow and why is this caused?

Comment: I would read this Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo

Comment: thank you for directing me to that thread. it helps

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `2147483647`.
If you reverse that, you get `7463847412`.

That value is obviously outside the range supported by `int`.
If you *calculate* the reverse, you'll get silent overflow.

```
int rev = 0;
for (int val = Integer.MAX_VALUE; val != 0; val /= 10)
    rev = rev * 10 + val % 10;
System.out.println(rev); // prints: -1126087180   <== Result of overflow
```

If you parse reversed string, you'll get parse exception.

```
String revStr = new StringBuilder().append(Integer.MAX_VALUE).reverse().toString();
System.out.println(revStr); // prints: 7463847412
rev = Integer.parseInt(revStr); // throws: NumberFormatException: For input string: "7463847412"
```

You can also guard against overflow by using the `xxxExact` methods of `Math`:

```
int rev = 0;
for (int val = Integer.MAX_VALUE; val != 0; val /= 10)
    rev = Math.addExact(Math.multiplyExact(rev, 10), val % 10); // throws: ArithmeticException: integer overflow
```