# What would cause a for loop to decrement when it's supposed to increment?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, increment, decrement

I wrote a method to calculate how long ago a father was twice as old as his son and in how many years from now this would be true. Unexpectedly, it returns "-2 years ago" for an 8-year-old father and a 3-year-old son. Equally unexpectedly, it returns "-1 years from now" for a 3-year-old father and a 2-year-old son. I am not concerned about how to improve the code because I already know how to do this. Instead, I am puzzled about why the for loop counter appears to be decrementing when it's supposed to increment.

Here is my code.

```
public class TwiceAsOld {

    public static void twiceAsOld (int currentFathersAge, int currentSonsAge) {

        int yearsAgo;
        int yearsFromNow;
        int pastFathersAge = currentFathersAge;
        int pastSonsAge = currentSonsAge;
        int futureFathersAge = currentFathersAge;
        int futureSonsAge = currentSonsAge;

        for (yearsAgo = 0; pastFathersAge != 2 * pastSonsAge; yearsAgo++) {
            pastFathersAge--;
            pastSonsAge--;
        }

        System.out.println("The father was last twice as old as the son " + yearsAgo + " years ago.");

        for (yearsFromNow = 0; futureFathersAge != 2 * futureSonsAge; yearsFromNow++) {
            futureFathersAge++;
            futureSonsAge++;
        }

        System.out.println("The father will be twice as old as the son in " + yearsFromNow + " years from now.");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        twiceAsOld(8, 3);
        twiceAsOld(3, 2);
    }
}
```

With twiceAsOld(8, 3), the for loop's increment appears to have reversed itself to count down from 0 instead of up. With twiceAsOld(3, 2), the -1 might stand for an error indicating that the father has never been twice as old as his son and never will be. What I don't understand is what would cause a for loop to start decrementing the i value when it's supposed to increment. I was expecting the counter to increment indefinitely until the program ran out of memory.

I already know how to improve this program, but I am curious about how the counter in a for loop can decrease when it's supposed to increase. Can anybody explain this?

(UPDATE: Thanks everyone for your answers. I can't believe I forgot about integer overflow. I tried making the variables longs instead of integers, but this made the program even slower. Anyway, now I realize that the counter was incrementing all along until it overflew and landed at a negative value.)

Comment: Since there's no decrement of that value, it is almost certainly an integer overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It became negative because that is what happens in Java when an int calculation overflows.

Take a look at 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2

It says that

> If an integer addition overflows, then the result is the low-order bits of the mathematical sum as represented in some sufficiently large two's-complement format. If overflow occurs, then the sign of the result is not the same as the sign of the mathematical sum of the two operand values.

Answer (score 3):

Didn't you notice that your program runs quite slowly? :)

For the (8, 3) years ago case, your for loop keeps looping and looping, trying to find a year that the father is twice as old, but as we know, the father will only become twice as old *in the future*, but not in the past. The for loop doesn't know this and it will try very hard to find such a year. It tries *so* hard that `yearsAgo` is incremented past the max value of `int`. This causes an [overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo), and  the value of `yearsAgo` will "wrap back around" to the minimum value of `int`, which is a negative number. And then this negative number will get incremented many many times, until -2.

The same goes for the other case.

To fix this, you can add if statements to check if the results are negative:

```
public static void twiceAsOld (int currentFathersAge, int currentSonsAge) {

    int yearsAgo;
    int yearsFromNow;
    int pastFathersAge = currentFathersAge;
    int pastSonsAge = currentSonsAge;
    int futureFathersAge = currentFathersAge;
    int futureSonsAge = currentSonsAge;


    for (yearsAgo = 0; pastFathersAge != 2 * pastSonsAge; yearsAgo++) {

        pastFathersAge--;
        pastSonsAge--;
    }

    // Here!
    if (yearsAgo >= 0) {
        System.out.println("The father was last twice as old as the son " + yearsAgo + " years ago.");
    }

    for (yearsFromNow = 0; futureFathersAge != 2 * futureSonsAge; yearsFromNow++) {
        futureFathersAge++;
        futureSonsAge++;
    }

    if (yearsFromNow >= 0) {
        System.out.println("The father will be twice as old as the son in " + yearsFromNow + " years from now.");
    }

}
```

You can also stop the loop when it reaches negative values to make your program faster:

```
for (yearsAgo = 0; pastFathersAge != 2 * pastSonsAge && yearsAgo >= 0; yearsAgo++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

When I debug your code I can see that `yearsAgo` is incrementing without bound, causing `pastFathersAge` and `pastSonsAge` to go into negatives. This is causing negative integer overflow. This happens because your condition `pastFathersAge != 2 * pastSonsAge` is never met (rather, never NOT met). Not until your `futureFathersAge` has gone all the way through the negatives, back into positives, and finally settles on -2.

The moral of the story is to make certain that your terminating condition for your loop can always can be met. Don't use `!=`, use `>=` or `<=` instead.