# Java: Converting absolute value of BigInteger into intValue() resulting negative value

Tags: java, cryptography

I'm trying to do a BigInteger exponent calculation. For my calculation, I am trying to subtract m1 from m2 (both are BigInteger) and get a positive value, but if I convert this positive number to an int number, I end up getting a negative value.

```
BigInteger m1 = new BigInteger("2905012217");
BigInteger m2 = new BigInteger("534500746");
int exp = m2.subtract(m1).abs().intValue();
System.out.println(exp);

BigInteger g1 = new BigInteger("2");
BigInteger output_test_g1 = g1.pow(exp);
```

> output:

```
m1:2905012217
m2:534500746
exp:-1924455825
```

> Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Negative exponent
    at java.base/java.math.BigInteger.pow(BigInteger.java:2401)
    at FHEv1.homomorphicEqualityTest(FHEv1.java:195)
    at FHEv1.main(FHEv1.java:323)
```

Answer (score 0):

Integer overflow. [How does Java handle integer underflows and overflows and how would you check for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo)

Too high and overflow to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and continue counting if nessecary. Too low and go to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and continue counting if nessecary.

For example,

```
int A = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
A++;
//A should be Integer.MIN_VALUE, correct me if I am wrong
```