# Int turning into negative number

Tags: android

I'm attempting to make a game in which I need to store a large number. I am currently using a int but the number keeps turning negative. Is there a reason this would be happening?

Comment: With some code sample you'll get an answer.

Comment: Its likely that you may be encountering an integer overflow, but theres no way to figure that out unless you show us the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Java handle integer underflows and overflows and how would you check for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo)

Answer (score 1):

This could be because your value is exceeding the range that a `int` can store. Try using the `long` variable rather then `int`