# What happens when I assign value larger than byte?

Tags: java, casting, byte

What happens when I assign value larger than byte?

According to official oracle documentation, [Byte](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) is

- > Byte: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer.
  >   It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).
  >   The byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays,
  >   where the memory savings actually matters. They can also be used in
  >   place of int where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact
  >   that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of
  >   documentation

My code is

```
public class B
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        byte b;
        b=(byte)129;
        System.out.println("b="+b);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
b=-127
```

What happens when I assign value larger than byte. Java compiler will report an error.
I will go if I cast this value to byte

```
byte b = (byte) 128;
```

I do not understand the output of this program?

Comment: overflow happens

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger why is the program output is 127 with a minus sign. should not it be 127 only?

Comment: my previous comment was for the question before you changed it (*"Error 
 
incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte.
"*) ! Documentation: [5.1.3. Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger why is there a minus sign in output. Thanks for documentation link

Comment: Dr. Lanning: That, Detective, is the "right question." - I, Robot! because the highest bit of byte is set: 129 = `1000 0001` in binary - read the documentation: "*this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input value*"

Comment: @Aman How does Java handle integer underflows and overflows and how would you check for it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo This post is about int but concept is same for byte.

Comment: Note: only get compiler error when not converting to `byte` that is `b = 129; ` (without cast)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For byte type, you only have 8 bits to store the value. You can have only 256 distinct values (2^8 = 256). Java represents negative values with '1' as the highest bit:

```
-128 (dec) => 10000000 (bit)
-127 (dec) => 10000001 (bit)
... 
-1   (dec) => 11111111 (bit)
0    (dec) => 00000000 (bit)
+1   (dec) => 00000001 (bit)
+127 (dec) => 01111111 (bin)
```

When you try to set a value that needs more than one byte to store then setting the lowest byte to a byte value happens:

```
+129 (dec) => 00000000 00000000 00000000 10000001  (int representation)

but 10000001 (bit) is -127 (dec) in byte representation of java type (as described above)
```

To have a better understanding of the overflow problem in Java, see the article: https://medium.com/@jeanvillete/java-numeric-overflow-underflow-d6b206f96d88

Answer (score 4):

`129` is an integer literal and, since not followed by `L` or `l`, it is of type `int`. This has 32 bits (4 bytes):

```
0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 0000  1000 0001
```

When *cast* to `byte` [5.1.3. Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) is done which discard all but the lower 8 bits so the values fits into `byte`.

In your example we will end with just the lower 8 bits

```
1000 0001
```

since Java uses two's complement to represent `byte`, this number is considered negative since the highest bit is set.

If the value was 257, its binary representation would be:

```
0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 0001  0000 0001
```

converted to `byte` as:

```
0000 0001
```

or just `+1` (highest bit not set).

Links:

- [3.10.1. Integer Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) <sub>Java Language Specification</sub>
- [4.2.1. Integral Types and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) <sub>Java Language Specification</sub>
- [5.1.3. Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) <sub>Java Language Specification</sub>
- [Two's Complement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1049722/85421) <sub>Stackoverflow</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Beacause byte datatype is of 1 byte as per name. so, its range is -127 to +126 (i.e capacity is 256). Hence +129  cannot be stored in byte datatype. so +129 is truncated to -127.

Comment: not rounded, truncated - "*A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits,*"

Comment: @Sachin Maharjan Thanks for answer! Can you help with how rounding is done in java?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger sorry, my bad.

Comment: Byte range is [-128..127].