# Why do I get 38528 when casting 10000000 to char?

Tags: java, casting, integer-overflow

Java uses 32 bits for the char tipe - so the max value is 65536.

But the following code give me the result reported in the title.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 10000000;
    char b = 33;
    b = (char)a;
    System.out.println((int)b);

}
```

Comment: You are observing an overflow. Not sure what you expected, a crash? Java does not crash on overflows.

Comment: What value did you expect to get, and *why* did you expect that? If you thought `65535`, then you should read up on how [Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) works in Java.

Comment: I presume you meant 16 bits, giving 65536 possible values.  32 bits gives 4,294,967,296 possible values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `char` is 16bit, not 32bit.

`65535` is the maximum value of a `char`, and `10000000` is greater than that, so you cannot store that value in a `char`.

`10000000` in binary is `100110001001011010000000`

Now when casting that to `char` all the bits left of the 16 bits that "fit" are dropped, leaving you with `1001011010000000`.

And binary `1001011010000000` in decimal is `38528`.

Comment: Thanks so much ! I now understand why this code gives me this result !

Comment: I was expecting 65536 as a result.

Comment: I started today to learn Java, sorry for the stupid question :)

Comment: Not a stupid question, otherwise you'd have downvotes instead of upvotes. It's a valid and understandable beginner's question. It makes sense to assume that the value gets rounded down instead of binary bits being dropped. Keep on asking and learning, that's how we all started.

Answer (score 3):

> Java uses 32 bits for the char tipe

no, Java uses `16` bit `char`s.

> so the max value is 65536.

Almost - in terms of what is the `char`'s max value, it's `65535`, however, the max value of 2s-complement 32 bit value is 2<sup>31</sup>, which is `2147483647`.

> But the following code give me the result reported in the title.
>
> ```
> int a = 10000000;
> char b = 33;
> b = (char)a;
> ```

Well, `10000000` is sure greater than `65535`, isn't it? What did you expect when trying to fit that number into a `char`? What you got is an [overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo).

Comment: *"so the max value is 6553**6**"* No, max value is 6553**5**.