# How to chanege the output of the result?

Tags: java, for-loop, math, sum

I am trying to summation,where the baseNumber is from 1-4 and the expNumber is,i  tried to use the for loop but isnt work and dont know where the problem is.Where the i shoudl get raised until 4 and so the basnum.

I tried to change places of number but what the weirdest thing is the sum get sometimes negative.

public static void main(String[] args)
    {

```
    int basenum = 1;
    int exp = 2;
    metoda(basenum,exp);

}
public static void metoda(int basenum,int exp) 
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) 
    {
        int sum = basenum * basenum;
        basenum++;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }


}
```

(Edited) now i get 1,4,9,25(those answer that i wanted) but now i want instead of all number i want to output the 1+4+9+25=30(the 30 as output).

Comment: Integer overflow I guess.  Your `basenum` is growing much faster than `i`.

Comment: You're trying to loop up to `basenum` but increasing `basenum` each turn (until it overflows).

Comment: Run your code step-by-step under debug and see for yourself.

Comment: Debug your code. After the first iteration, `basenum` is 16, `i` is 2, less than `basenum`, so it will enter the loop again, at after it `basenum` is `2^8`, `i` is 3, then `basenum` is 2^16, and then an integer overflow happens, because 2^32 is bigger then Integer.MAX_VALUE, and it becomes 0. Now `i` is larger, you exit the loop and return 0.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are using `basenum` instead of `exp` to define power

```
for(int i = 1; i <= basenum; i++)  // should be `i <= exp`
```

and because of this I guess you are exceeding the range of `int` having negative number as result. For more information take a look at this topic:

- [How does Java handle integer underflows and overflows and how would you check for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo)

solution for this (after setting proper `exp` power value ofc) is to realise what operations do you want to allow and use either `long` or [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to provide proper range

Comment: [link]https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/14a5d4e143960f07dd1be548c683664975e536f8
That is actually what i tried to do.