# Why does a Java overflow returns 0 as a value

Tags: java, overflow

I have the following snippet of code

```
public class DN1{
  public static void main(String argv[]){
    int a = 869;
    int b = 85;
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
      b += b;
    }
    System.out.println(b);
  }
}
```

This code clearly overflows at `i = 24`

I was wondering why after a couple of loops `b` is set to 0. What is this overflow behaviour and how exactly does it work in Java?

I expected the output to be variable between `-2^31 to +2^31` but it's not, why is that?

Comment: That's [an answer](https://dzone.com/articles/overflow-and-underflow-data)?

Comment: "I expected the output to be variable between -2^31 to +2^31" Can you explain why you think so?

Comment: @Sweeper i expected it to be between Integer.MAX_VALUE and Integer.MIN_VALUE

Comment: @curiosa it says that it reaches zero for non-integer data types

Comment: Try debbuging it and see values step by step and see what happens when `i=31`

Comment: b reaches Integer.MIN_VALUE, MIN_VALUE + MIN_VALUE = 0, 0 + 0 = 0

Comment: @michalk it overflows as expected at i=24 into a negative value. Then it switches between positive and negative until i=31 where b becomes equal to 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more precise, the output is in the range you specified. 0 qualifies as being between `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Modifying your code a bit you can take a look at what's going on and print the actual binary

```
int a = 869;
int b = 85;
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
    System.out.printf(
            "Iteration %d: b = %d; b+b = %d; bin(b) = %s; bin(b+b) = %s%n",
            i, b, (b+b), Integer.toBinaryString(b), Integer.toBinaryString(b+b));
            b += b;
}
System.out.println(b);
```

Which gives the following output

```
Iteration 0: b = 85; b+b = 170; bin(b) = 1010101; bin(b+b) = 10101010
Iteration 1: b = 170; b+b = 340; bin(b) = 10101010; bin(b+b) = 101010100
Iteration 2: b = 340; b+b = 680; bin(b) = 101010100; bin(b+b) = 1010101000
Iteration 3: b = 680; b+b = 1360; bin(b) = 1010101000; bin(b+b) = 10101010000
Iteration 4: b = 1360; b+b = 2720; bin(b) = 10101010000; bin(b+b) = 101010100000
Iteration 5: b = 2720; b+b = 5440; bin(b) = 101010100000; bin(b+b) = 1010101000000
Iteration 6: b = 5440; b+b = 10880; bin(b) = 1010101000000; bin(b+b) = 10101010000000
Iteration 7: b = 10880; b+b = 21760; bin(b) = 10101010000000; bin(b+b) = 101010100000000
Iteration 8: b = 21760; b+b = 43520; bin(b) = 101010100000000; bin(b+b) = 1010101000000000
Iteration 9: b = 43520; b+b = 87040; bin(b) = 1010101000000000; bin(b+b) = 10101010000000000
Iteration 10: b = 87040; b+b = 174080; bin(b) = 10101010000000000; bin(b+b) = 101010100000000000
Iteration 11: b = 174080; b+b = 348160; bin(b) = 101010100000000000; bin(b+b) = 1010101000000000000
Iteration 12: b = 348160; b+b = 696320; bin(b) = 1010101000000000000; bin(b+b) = 10101010000000000000
Iteration 13: b = 696320; b+b = 1392640; bin(b) = 10101010000000000000; bin(b+b) = 101010100000000000000
Iteration 14: b = 1392640; b+b = 2785280; bin(b) = 101010100000000000000; bin(b+b) = 1010101000000000000000
Iteration 15: b = 2785280; b+b = 5570560; bin(b) = 1010101000000000000000; bin(b+b) = 10101010000000000000000
Iteration 16: b = 5570560; b+b = 11141120; bin(b) = 10101010000000000000000; bin(b+b) = 101010100000000000000000
Iteration 17: b = 11141120; b+b = 22282240; bin(b) = 101010100000000000000000; bin(b+b) = 1010101000000000000000000
Iteration 18: b = 22282240; b+b = 44564480; bin(b) = 1010101000000000000000000; bin(b+b) = 10101010000000000000000000
Iteration 19: b = 44564480; b+b = 89128960; bin(b) = 10101010000000000000000000; bin(b+b) = 101010100000000000000000000
Iteration 20: b = 89128960; b+b = 178257920; bin(b) = 101010100000000000000000000; bin(b+b) = 1010101000000000000000000000
Iteration 21: b = 178257920; b+b = 356515840; bin(b) = 1010101000000000000000000000; bin(b+b) = 10101010000000000000000000000
Iteration 22: b = 356515840; b+b = 713031680; bin(b) = 10101010000000000000000000000; bin(b+b) = 101010100000000000000000000000
Iteration 23: b = 713031680; b+b = 1426063360; bin(b) = 101010100000000000000000000000; bin(b+b) = 1010101000000000000000000000000
Iteration 24: b = 1426063360; b+b = -1442840576; bin(b) = 1010101000000000000000000000000; bin(b+b) = 10101010000000000000000000000000
Iteration 25: b = -1442840576; b+b = 1409286144; bin(b) = 10101010000000000000000000000000; bin(b+b) = 1010100000000000000000000000000
Iteration 26: b = 1409286144; b+b = -1476395008; bin(b) = 1010100000000000000000000000000; bin(b+b) = 10101000000000000000000000000000
Iteration 27: b = -1476395008; b+b = 1342177280; bin(b) = 10101000000000000000000000000000; bin(b+b) = 1010000000000000000000000000000
Iteration 28: b = 1342177280; b+b = -1610612736; bin(b) = 1010000000000000000000000000000; bin(b+b) = 10100000000000000000000000000000
Iteration 29: b = -1610612736; b+b = 1073741824; bin(b) = 10100000000000000000000000000000; bin(b+b) = 1000000000000000000000000000000
Iteration 30: b = 1073741824; b+b = -2147483648; bin(b) = 1000000000000000000000000000000; bin(b+b) = 10000000000000000000000000000000
Iteration 31: b = -2147483648; b+b = 0; bin(b) = 10000000000000000000000000000000; bin(b+b) = 0
```

You're essentially shifting bits to the left, logically equivalent to multiplying by 2 at each iteration. You end up with binary `10000000000000000000000000000000` at iteration 31 and shifting this to the left will push the `1` out of the sequence so you're left with `00000000000000000000000000000000`. This happens at iteration 31 regardless of your starting value for b (you only have 32 bits to work with, positions 0-31).

Addendum: other ways to write `b += b`:

```
b <<= 1
b *= 2
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If you feel it's satisfactory please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a print statement inside that for loop, something like below:

```
public static void main(String argv[]){
    int a = 869;
    int b = 85;
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
      b += b;
      System.out.println(b);          <----- Add this to see 
    }
    System.out.println(b);
  }
```

### Output:

```
170
340
680
1360
2720
5440
10880
21760
43520
87040
174080
348160
696320
1392640
2785280
5570560
11141120
22282240
44564480
89128960
178257920
356515840
713031680
1426063360
-1442840576
1409286144
-1476395008
1342177280
-1610612736
1073741824
-2147483648
0
0
0
0
0
0
.....
```

And so on and on till the loop ends.

Note that the limit you've set has been crossed way too earlier. Now the reason why you see 0 from here onwards is because of the link as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3001879/3838328) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3001995/3838328)

Do note in detailed the answer i.e 2nd link shared. That would help you understand why it behaves the way it behaves and I think it is not just limited to `int` but also in case of `long`, `double` and all other `numeric` types.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but @curiosa's links only talks about non-integer data types returning 0. I still don't understand why an int does that. Thanks.

Comment: You can check this answer where it has been described as why this happens https://stackoverflow.com/a/3001995/3838328 and its pretty thorough.