# javascript to java gives different return value

Tags: javascript, java

this js code

```
function keygen( serial) {
 return parseInt(serial.replace(/-/g, ''), 16)
}
keygen("C6AD-0E40")
```

gives

> 3333230144

and this java code

```
private int keygens(String serial) {

        String s=serial.replaceAll("[-]", "");
     int dec=Integer.parseUnsignedInt(s,16);
                 return dec+dec+dec; //one dec give negative value wondering why !!
}
        System.out.print(keygens("C6AD-0E40"));
```

gives

> 1409755840

**WHY ?** , i need to get the same return value of js function

Appreciate any help

Comment: `3_333_230_144` is bigger than `2_147_483_647` which is the largest possible `int` in java.  Use `Long.parseUnsignedLong(String, int)` instead.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo for more details on integer overflow.

Comment: @azurefrog thank you so much for help, it worked