# Issue with large number

Tags: java, math, java-8, factorial, largenumber

I'm trying to count the number of trailing zero with a factorial.

e.g

4! = 24 So you retrieve 0.

9! = 362880 So you retrieve 1.

10! = 9! x 10 = 3628800 So you retrieve 2.

11! = 10! x 11 = 3.99168E7 So you retrieve 2.

```
    static double factorial(double n) {
        double f = 1;
        for(int i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++) {
            f *= i;
        }
        return f;
    }

    static int numberOfZeros(double f) {
        int ten = 1;
        int count = 0;
        for(;f%Math.pow(10, ten) == 0;count++) {

            ten++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

this codes are Okay until number n is 22. but when i try to put 23 into then count is 0.
Of course, mathematically 23! has trailing zeros.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to calculate the factorial to count trailing zeroes.

Just see how many times you can divide by powers of 5 (which is the larger factor of 10).  This works since any number with a trailing zero will be divisible by 10. You need to do the powers of 5 to catch those times when 5 occurs more than once.

- `for 45!  =  45/25 = 1 + 45/5 = 9 = 10 zeroes.`
- `for 150! =  150/125 = 1  150/25 = 6, 150/5 = 30  so 1 + 6 + 30 = 37 zeros.`

Now all you have to do is code it.

Comment: Instead of dividing by 125 (5³), just keep dividing by 5, using `int` math, until you reach 0. E.g. `150 / 5 = 30` (add 30 to total), `30 / 5 = 6` (add 6 to total), `6 / 5 = 1` (add 1 to total), and done since `1 < 5`. Result: `total = 30 + 6 + 1 = 37`

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code isn't working is that a double type can only hold 64 bits. Let's do the calculation:

A bit has two possible values, so 2^64 is the largest number a double could hold... **if we aren't accounting for negative numbers.** Of course, Java doubles support negative values, so we divide 2^64 (18,446,744,073,709,551,616) by two, and then subtract 1 (Because Java takes one number from the positive range to store zero). As a result, we get 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, which represents the positive bound for the Java double type, or in other words, the biggest positive number a double can store.

Now, 23 factorial is a very big number:
25,852,016,738,884,976,640,000

9,223,372,036,854,775,807
Above is the range for a double. Just by looking at the widths of the numbers, we can see that 23! exceeds the range for a double. Therefore, your double value will [overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo) and you won't get the right answer.

You should consider using the BigInteger class to handle such large numbers and ensure you are getting accurate answers.

[GeeksForGeeks BigInteger tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biginteger-class-in-java/)
[Java API documentation for BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: You don't need `BigInteger`  because it isn't necessary to calculate the value.

Comment: That's true, I was trying to provide a way where they could refactor their current code without changing the underlying concept.

Comment: A double has 64 bits, but only 53 bits of mantissa. But, as @WJS says, there's no need to calculate the full value, only the number of factors of 5 it contains. (There will always be more 2's than 5's, so 5 is the 'limiting reagent,' as a chemist would say.)

Comment: @DavidConrad Ah yes, I was thinking about the long type. However, what would be the use of using a double here? Since we are dealing with positive integer factorials isn't it impossible to obtain a floating-point value?

Comment: You're right. But OP is using a double because Math.pow takes and returns doubles.