# Get a boolean answer from a custom Comparator

Tags: java

I have learned how to create my own `Comparator`, for example, create a simple one to compare based on `absolute value`

```
class absComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return a * a - b * b;
    }
}
```

And of course, this can be used for a customized sort:

```
List<Integer> list_1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2));
list_1.sort(new absComparator());
>>> [0, -1, 1, -2, 2, -3]
```

So this is all good, but what if I want to just compare two Integers based on this comparator to give a boolean value?

```
// Currently:
System.out.println(-2>1);
>>> false
```

So how do I get a `true` by comparing `-2` and `1`, using `absComparator`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `compare` directly and check the result against `0` using the same relational operator. If you want to check `-2 > 1`, pass those two numbers in as parameters and check if the result is `> 0`.

```
Comparator<Integer> comparator = new absComparator();
System.out.println(comparator.compare(-2, 1) > 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

IMO, method like `isGreaterThan`, `isLessThan` should be added to [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) interface.
Since we don't have these in this moment, we can create our own interface extending `Comparator`, and add [default method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) `isGreaterThan`, `isLessThan`, as follow:

```java
public interface EnhancedComparator<T> extends Comparator<T> {
    default boolean isGreaterThan(T target, T compareTo) {
        return this.compare(target, compareTo) > 0;
    }

    default boolean isLessThan(T target, T compareTo) {
        return this.compare(target, compareTo) < 0;
    }
}

public class AbsoluteValueComparator implements EnhancedComparator<Integer> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        a = Math.abs(a);
        b = Math.abs(b);
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
}

public class EnhancedComparatorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EnhancedComparator<Integer> absoluteValueComparator = new AbsoluteValueComparator();
        System.out.println("2 greater than 3 " + absoluteValueComparator.isGreaterThan(2, 3));
        System.out.println("-3 greater than -2 " + absoluteValueComparator.isGreaterThan(-3, -2));
        System.out.println("2 less than 3 " + absoluteValueComparator.isLessThan(2, 3));
        System.out.println("-3 less than -2 " + absoluteValueComparator.isLessThan(-3, -2));
    }
}
```

---

P.S.
`a * a` may overflow, you may refer to my example for more robust comparison.

---

References
[The Java™ Tutorials Default Method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html)
[Java Doc Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)
[How does Java handle integer underflows and overflows and how would you check for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo#:%7E:text=Java%20doesn%27t%20do%20anything,with%20positive%20and%20negative%20integers.&text=Underflow%20occurs%20in%20integer%20arithmetic,0%20or%200%20and%201.)

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support operator overloading.

That being said, you can easily define your own static method for it:

```
private static final Comparator<Integer> ABS_CMP = new AbsComparator();
public static boolean gtAbs (int a, int b) {
    return ABS_CMP.compare(a, b) > 0;
}
```

And then import it statically and use it operator-like:

```java
import static your.UtilityClass.gteAbs;

[...]

int a = 5;
int b = -6;

if (gtAbs(a,b)) {
    // do work
}
```

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Well. if you compare an int using `> 0` you get a boolean. I think thats pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

First, your problem is that you are not using your comparator.

```
class absComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return a * a - b * b;
    }
}

absComparator comp = new absComparator();

if (comp.compare(-2,1)) > 0) {
   System.out.println(true);
}
```

But your comparator has a more fundamental problem.  The following also
prints true.  This is due to integer overflow when you subtract the products.

```
if (comp.compare(12345678, 123456789) > 0) {        
    System.out.println(true);
}
```

To correct the problem, write your comparator as follows:

```
class absComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        // eliminate the need for products by 
        // getting abs (Math.abs() also available);      
        int a1 = a >= 0 ? a : -a;
        int b1 = b >= 0 ? b : -b;
        // but you still should not subract as overflow can
        // still happen for large values of a1 and b1
        return a1 > b1 ? 1 : a1 < b1 ? -1 : 0;
        // or return Integer.compare(a1,b1);
        // or if (a1 > b1) {
        //         return 1;
        //     }
        //     if (a1 < b1) {
        //        return -1;
        //     }
        //     return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an instance of your comparator:

```
absComparator comp = new absComparator();

int result = comp.compare(-2, 1);

if (result > 0) {
    // -2 > 1 (according to your comparator)
}
```